# How do I list all the files in a commit?

Tags: git, git-show

How can I print a plain list of all files that were part of a given commit?

Although the following lists the files, it also includes unwanted diff information for each:

```
git show a303aa90779efdd2f6b9d90693e2cbbbe4613c1d
```

Comment: I came here looking for something a bit different. I want to see all files modified for a set of commits and wound up using `git log --until 2013-05-21 --pretty="short" --name-only` with a good effect.

Comment: Use this command to get all changes from previous `n` commits till `master`: `git diff-tree  --name-status -r @{3} master`

Comment: `git diff --name-only master` - To list ALL changed files on current branch, comparing to master branch.

Comment: You can check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563726/how-can-i-see-the-changes-in-a-git-commit/68474286#68474286

Answer (score 4800, accepted):

**Preferred Way** (because it's a *plumbing* command; meant to be programmatic):

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only bd61ad98 -r
index.html
javascript/application.js
javascript/ie6.js
```

**Another Way** (less preferred for scripts, because it's a *porcelain* command; meant to be user-facing)

```
$ git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98    
index.html
javascript/application.js
javascript/ie6.js
```

---

- The `--no-commit-id` suppresses the commit ID output.
- The `--pretty` argument specifies an empty format string to avoid the cruft at the beginning.
- The `--name-only` argument shows only the file names that were affected (Thanks Hank). Use `--name-status` instead, if you want to see what happened to each file (**D**eleted, **M**odified, **A**dded)
- The `-r` argument is to recurse into sub-trees

Comment: This shows also all the files which have been untracked with `git rm --cached <file>`. This makes _commit_ only a technical term in this case and showing a bunch of files (as part of the commit) is totally misleading because Git does not show whether a file were added or removed.

Comment: This isn't working for a merge commit. Message: `Merge branch '<branch>' of bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx into master`

Comment: It should be noted that `diff-tree` won't work when looking at the root commit.

Comment: Replacing the `--name-only` option with `--name-status` will give more clear summary.

Comment: How do you get the same list but with absolute paths?

Comment: If you want it to work on the root commit, use the --root flag.  From the man page: "When --root is specified the initial commit will be shown as a big creation event. This is equivalent to a diff against the NULL tree."

Comment: `git log --name-only -n 1 <hash>`
The last commit would be: `git log --name-only -n 1 HEAD~1..HEAD`

Comment: What does the -r stand for ?

Comment: @user1598390 -r recurses into sub-trees.  You can learn about more options with `man git-diff-tree`.

Comment: why not just do a simple `git show --name-only <COMMIT_ID>`?

Comment: If anyone is wondering (like I was) why the first way is "preferred," it goes back to @drizzt 's comment;  `git show` is "porcelain" (meant to be user facing) and `git diff-tree` is "plumbing" (meant to be used programmatically, e.g. from scripts). The interface for the former may change over time (so the git maintainers could drop `--name-only` although I don't imagine they _would_) for useability reasons, whereas the interface for the latter will be kept as stable as possible for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I would prefer to create an alias for the second because using it without a commit hash defaults to the most recent commit.  This is particularly useful when rebasing.

Comment: `--pretty=""` will also work for most things and is easier to remember, e.g. `vi $(git show --pretty="" --name-only)`

Comment: What is `bd61ad98` ?

Comment: @Kurt You don't need to specify `HEAD~1..HEAD` as HEAD is the default. Also you need to use `--pretty=""` to remove all the log cruft. The command should be: `git log --pretty="" --name-only -n 1`

Comment: @Eido95 It’s (probably) the first eight characters of some commit hash. It can be any reference to a commit, like a tag, branch name, full 40-character hash, or `HEAD`.

Comment: To see all files affected by a list of commit ids you can do this: `git log | grep commit | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 git diff-tree ... | sort | uniq`

Comment: I had some trouble because I was trying to get the files of a merge. Just had to specify the short hash of the parent and then the merge itself, like:
`git diff --name-only 8dd6615f24 880ba9a`

Comment: @Colin Alternatively, add [the `-m` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#git-diff-tree--m): `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -m -r bd61ad98`.  That may provide non-unique lines - it lists files from each merge head separately from the other merge heads.  On UNIX-like platforms, you can tack `|sort|uniq` on the end if that's an issue.

Comment: `git show --stat (hash)` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406493/3449673) from @VaTo outputs a bit more than you asked for but is easy to remember and perfectly fine in case you are a human and not a machine.
Maybe worth mentioning here in the accepted answer to provide an _easy to type_ alternative.

Comment: I parse porcelain commands in scripts all the time. What's the problem?

Comment: @OhComeOn porcelain commands are tweaked to look nice for the user. The Git developers might change the layout (introducing different formatting, like adding separators or using additional words for better description etc.) of the output any time. If you parse that output you may end up having issues in future since you tailored your scripts to that specific layout. "plumbing" commands should however look the same, whatever git version you are using.

Comment: On my machine there was no difference between including, or not including `--pretty=""`. Why is that?

Comment: @RyanMcGeary the above git command is not working for a merge from master to dev branch. Is there any other way available to do it?

Comment: Using this with `git rev-parse --short HEAD` you will get changed files for your current commit:```git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r `git rev-parse --short HEAD` ```

Comment: How to get tree-ish through git command?

I'm trying to checkout only files which were modified in last commit. The above commands works well but I'm not able to get tree-ish of last commit through command

Comment: For a discussion of *porcelain* vs. *plumbing*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git), as well as others in that question thread.

Comment: how do you set this particular command as a .gitconfig alias that takes in a commit hash ?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan, why couldn't I provide `HEAD` to `git diff-tree` directly? Why `git rev-parse` should be used?

Comment: *NB* `diff-tree` outputs renames as both the old and new name. `show` only outputs the new name. Use `diff-tree --find-renames` for the similar behavior

Comment: Plumbing vs porcelain is a genius nomenclature which I have not encountered before. I will be sure to remember it

Comment: Well there is a reason why your less preferred way might actually be best for certain scripts, for instance because the hash is the last thing specified, you can then pipe the hash(es) to another command.  For instance the following will list every file in every commit: `git log | grep commit | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git show --pretty="" --name-only`

Answer (score 353):

If you want to get the list of changed files:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-ish>
```

If you want to get the list of all files in a commit, you can use

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <commit-ish>
```

Comment: The ls-tree with --name-only does not seem to work on 1.6.4.4 or 1.6.3.3. Do you think this is a bug ?

Comment: `git ls-tree --name-only HEAD` (the <commit-ish> parameter is **required**; in this example it is HEAD) works for me with git version 1.6.4.3

Comment: It turns out the ordering of the parameters is significant here. The one in your post does not work, while the one in your response *does* work - at least until you update your post ;)

Comment: Thanks @krosenvold, I updated my post... Some git commands are not rewritten using parseopt, so ordering of options and non-option agruments might be significant.

Comment: that works better. with git show --pretty="format:" you still have one blank line in beginning, which is not that big problem, but when using it in scripts you have to remove it. So ls-tree works better for me

Comment: Pass `--no-commit-id` to avoid printing the SHA1, like so: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-ish>`

Comment: diff-tree doesn't return anything, possibly because the commit I refer to added files, but not changed any existing. ls-tree gives me a list of all files in the repo, not just the files added/altered in the last commit. I wonder if there's a 3rd command to just list all **new** files (i.e. added in that given commit)?

Comment: @CoDEmanX : You didn't miss adding `-r` / `-t` option, did you? Because diff-tree handles both modified and added files. If you want to list all new (added) files, use `git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id --diff-filter=A <commit-ish>`

Comment: The `-r` option is present. I realized that I supplied the wrong commit hash, and `diff-tree` appears to work on the correct commit. But still, it's strange that it doesn't return anything for a certain commit, which clearly contains a change to a file: http://pastebin.com/ED0pHtf5 `-diff-filter` works like a charm - many thanks!

Comment: @CoDEmanX note that `git diff d730c6` shows difference between commit and your working area; use `git diff d730c6^!` or `git show d730c6` instead

Comment: `git log --pretty="" --name-only` for me!

Comment: sorry what is an example scenario where list of files in a commit are different than the list of files changed? I just kinda experienced this scenario but cannot pinpoint what's happening.

Comment: @nanospeck : all files in a commit mean all files in a project at a specific revision (specific commit); commit can have changed only subset of those files.

Comment: The --diff-tree does not work after a merge

Comment: i've noticed that `git ls-tree --name-only -r` shows more complete list of files for merge commit - it shows not only the files that were modified during merge commit, but actually all the files brought to repo from 2 branches that made that merge commit.

Answer (score 317):

I'll just assume that [`gitk`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) is not desired for this. In that case, try `git show --name-only <sha>`.

Comment: --name-only is plenty in most cases where i needed it; Therefore, upvoted the shortest solution (and the only one that i'd remember in 1 try).

Comment: As someone who really likes CLI git, `gitk` is actually a decent way of reviewing the files and displaying the file that the diff is on. e.g. Code reviewing a monster commit from a peer.

Answer (score 277):

I personally use the combination of **--stat** and **--oneline** with the **show** command:

```
git show --stat --oneline HEAD
git show --stat --oneline b24f5fb
git show --stat --oneline HEAD^^..HEAD
```

If you do not like/want the addition/removal stats, you can replace **--stat** with **--name-only**

```
git show --name-only --oneline HEAD
git show --name-only --oneline b24f5fb
git show --name-only --oneline HEAD^^..HEAD
```

Comment: Very nice. To define an alias: `alias gits='git show --stat --oneline'`, then `gits` by itself shows the latest changes (in HEAD), while `gits b24f5fb` can be used to show any revision's changes.

Comment: One could also create a git alias... e.g. perhaps `git config --global alias.changes 'show --stat --oneline'`.  Then you can type `git changes` (with an optional commit-ish) and get the output from the first examples above.

Comment: Git for Windows requires double quotes: `git config --global alias.changes "show --stat --oneline"`

Comment: Nice. And unlike the accepted answer, `git show` also works for reviewing stashed changes: e.g. `git show --stat --oneline stash@{1}`

Comment: this is what I've really needed !
unlike " git diff-tree --name-status -r <commit_id>", with this command I may see affected files in the merge too !
thanks !

Answer (score 134):

You can also do

```
git log --name-only
```

and you can browse through various commits, commit messages and the changed files.

Type q to get your prompt back.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. BTW: use `git show 5944ad2a8b5 --name-only` to list the name of a specific commit

Comment: What is the difference compared to leaving `--name-only` out? Or in other words, what is it supposed to do and how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 77):

Recently I needed to list all changed files between two commits. So I used this (also *nix specific) command

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT | sort | uniq
```

Or as [Ethan points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit#comment27828076_2713363):

```
git diff --name-only START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT
```

Using `--name-status` will also include the change (added, modified, deleted, etc.) next to each file:

```
git diff --name-status START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT
```

Comment: If you use `git diff --name-status START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT` then you don't need the trailing `|sort | uniq`.

Comment: Correction to above comment: `git diff --name-only START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. How I used it: `git diff --name-only START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT | grep -v -e '**.png' -e '**.xml'`. I wanted a list of code changes only for a huge PR that had added thousands of PNGs and XML layouts.

Answer (score 73):

Simplest form:

`git show --stat (hash)`

That's easier to remember and it will give you all the information you need.

If you really want only the names of the files you could add the `--name-only` option.

`git show --stat --name-only (hash)`

Comment: --name-only will still include a couple of header lines containing information such as the author, date and the commit message.

Answer (score 53):

I use the **changed** [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) quite often. To set it up:

```
git config --global alias.changed 'show --pretty="format:" --name-only'
```

Then:

```
git changed (lists files modified in last commit)
git changed bAda55 (lists files modified in this commit)
git changed bAda55..ff0021 (lists files modified between those commits)
```

Similar commands that may be useful:

```
git log --name-status --oneline (very similar, but shows what actually happened M/C/D)
git show --name-only
```

Comment: It is there anything special about "changed"? Is it an arbitrary choice of a word? A convention? Something built-in?

Answer (score 51):

Use

```
git log --name-status
```

This will show you the commit id, message, the files changed and whether it was modified, created, added, or deleted. Somewhat of an all-in-one command.

Comment: this brings up a huge list of every recent commit, I have to hold down the ENTER button to see everything, then it locks my cmd.  no thanks.

Answer (score 48):

Try this command for name and changes number of lines

```
git show --stat <commit-hash>
```

Only show file names

```
git show --stat --name-only  <commit-hash>
```

For getting the last commit hash, try this command:

```
git log -1
```

Last commit with show files name and file status modify, create, or delete:

```
 git log -1 --oneline --name-status <commit-hash>
```

Or for all

```
git log
```

For more advanced git log information, read these articles:

- *[Git log format string cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/git-log-format)*
- *[git log cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/git-log)*

Comment: @DanFare "fatal: unrecognized argument: --names-only" from 2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: _"for all"_... just `git log` doesn't give you the filenames...

Answer (score 46):

**Using the standard `git diff` command** (also good for scripting):

```
git diff --name-only <sha>^ <sha>
```

**If you also want the status of the changed files:**

```
git diff --name-status <sha>^ <sha>
```

This works well with merge commits.

Answer (score 37):

To list the files changed on **a particular commit**:

```
git show --pretty=%gd --stat <commit_id>
```

To list the files changed on **recent commit**:

```
git show --pretty=%gd --stat
```

Answer (score 27):

```
$ git log 88ee8^..88ee8 --name-only --pretty="format:"
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 23):

```
git show --name-only a303aa90779efdd2f6b9d90693e2cbbbe4613c1d
```

Answer (score 22):

OK, there are a couple of ways to show all files in a particular commit...

To reduce the information and **show only names** of the files which committed, you simply can add `--name-only` or `--name-status` flag... These flags just show you the file names which are different from previous commits as you want...

So you can do `git diff` followed by `--name-only`, with two commit hashes after `<sha0> <sha1>`. Something like below:

```
git diff --name-only 5f12f15 kag9f02
```

I also created the below image to show all steps to go through in these situations:

[image: git diff --name-only 5f12f15 kag9f02]

Answer (score 20):

Use a simple one-line command, if you just want the list of files changed in the last commit:

```
git diff HEAD~1 --name-only
```

Answer (score 17):

There's also `git whatchanged`, which is more low level than `git log`

```
NAME
       git-whatchanged - Show logs with difference each commit introduces
```

It outputs the commit summary with a list of files beneath it with their modes and if they were added(`A`), deleted(`D`), or modified(`M`);

```
$ git whatchanged f31a441398fb7834fde24c5b0c2974182a431363
```

Would give something like:

```
commit f31a441398fb7834fde24c5b0c2974182a431363
Author: xx <xx@xx.nl>
Date:   Tue Sep 29 17:23:22 2015 +0200

    added fb skd and XLForm

:000000 100644 0000000... 90a20d7... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationToken.h
:000000 100644 0000000... b5006d0... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationToken.m
:000000 100644 0000000... 3e7b711... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.h
:000000 100644 0000000... 9c8a7ae... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.m
:000000 100644 0000000... bd6e7a1... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenSource.h
:000000 100644 0000000... 947f725... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenSource.m
:000000 100644 0000000... cf7dcdf... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFDefines.h
:000000 100644 0000000... 02af9ba... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFExecutor.h
:000000 100644 0000000... 292e27c... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFExecutor.m
:000000 100644 0000000... 827071d... A  Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFTask.h
...
```

I know this answer doesn't really match "with no extraneous information.", but I still think this list is more useful than just the filenames.

Comment: Plus, just one command `whatchanged` instead of supplying parameters.

Answer (score 17):

I use this to get the list of changed files in a merge commit

```
λ git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:"
configs/anotherconfig.xml
configs/configsInRepo.xml
```

or

```
λ git log -m -1 --name-status --pretty="format:"
A       configs/anotherconfig.xml
M       configs/configsInRepo.xml
```

Answer (score 16):

I use this to get the list of modified files between two changesets:

```
git diff --name-status <SHA1> <SHA2> | cut -f2
```

Comment: Yeah but the status can be quite handy at well (for isntance, you might want to grep to display all files except those that have been deleted with something like ``git diff --name-status .. | grep ^[^D] | cut -f2``

Answer (score 14):

I like to use

```
git show --stat <SHA1>^..<SHA2>
```

Answer (score 14):

I found a perfect answer to this:

```
git show --name-status --oneline <commit-hash>
```

So that I can know

- which files were just modified (M)
- Which files were newly added (A)
- Which files were deleted (D)

Answer (score 13):

I like this:

```
git diff --name-status <SHA1> <SHA1>^
```

Comment: I think this gets the `A` & `D` (add and delete) file statuses backwards, because it's showing the diff from the specified commit to the previous commit, instead of the other way around. It should be `git diff --name-status <SHA1>^ <SHA1>`.

Answer (score 10):

Display the log.

`COMMIT` can be blank (""), the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash, or a shortened version of the SHA-1 hash.

```
git log COMMIT -1 --name-only
```

This will list just the files and is very useful for further processing.

```
git log COMMIT -1 --name-only --pretty=format:"" | grep "[^\s]"
```

Answer (score 10):

List the files that changed in a commit:

```
git diff --name-only SHA1^ SHA1
```

This doesn't show log messages, extra newlines, or any other clutter. This works for any commit, not just the current one.

Comment: This two looks the same: `git diff SHA1^ SHA1` and `git show SHA1`.

Comment: @mrW Those commands produce similar output, but `git show` also shows the commit message

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps I missed it did anyone mention if you want to augment the log x previous commits using the 'log' command to include the names of the files effected then add --name-only on the end.

so:

```
git log -n3
```

to see the last comments of the last 3 commits.

```
git log -n3 --name-only
```

to see the comments and files effected in the last 3 commits.

Answer (score 9):

*Only* the file list (not even commit message):

```
git show --name-only --pretty=format:
```

E.g. open all changed files in your editor:

```
git show --name-only --pretty=format: | xargs "$EDITOR"
```

Comment: This works perfectly however it only shows the last commit. If you want to target a specific commit see answer by @Ryan McGeary

Comment: @Hamfri: No, it doesn't only work for the last commit. It's just the default of `git show`.

Answer (score 6):

A combination of `git show --stat` and a couple of **sed** commands should trim the data down for you:

```
git show --stat <SHA1> | sed -n "/ [\w]\*|/p" | sed "s/|.\*$//"
```

That will produce just the list of modified files.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple trick to view as a file listing. Just add `:` after the hash:

```
git show 9d3a52c474:
```

You can then drill in,

```
git show 9d3a52c474:someDir/someOtherDir
```

If you hit a file, you'll get the raw version of the file; which sometimes is what you want if you're only looking for a nice reference or key pieces of code (diffs can make everything a mess),

```
git show 9d3a52c474:someDir/someOtherDir/somefile
```

The only drawback of this method is that it doesn't easily show a tree of files.

Comment: It will not only find files changed in a commit, but all files that are in the tree of that commit. Great if you want that, but not so great if you want to see which files changed.

Answer (score 4):

If your commit happens to be at the initial `HEAD` position

```
git show HEAD@{0}
```

this should work fine.

Comment: All: An explanation would be in order. Why and how does it work?

Answer (score 4):

List all files in a commit tree:

```
git ls-tree --name-only --full-tree a21e610
```