# Git Interactive Merge?

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches with the exact same file (incase you are wondering it is a .sql file) and I want to interactively merge it.

Pretty much I want to open up a diff program like I do when there is a conflict (or command line) and select exactly what lines go where.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You might argue answers to this question behave more like "--squash" vs the basic merge most people use. The basic merge is great because it preserves git history; squash does not. Is an interactive approach incompatible with preserving things like author, commit message, past changes, etc?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, but it will mostly be by manually making that happen. You'll tell Git you're merging the two relevant branches, but that it shouldn't try to commit the result on its own, (*edited to add:* nor fast-forward if it thinks the merge is trivial):

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff branch-to-merge
```

Then you'll ask git for the file as it appeared in the two branches:

```
git show HEAD:filename >filename.HEAD
git show branch-to-merge:filename >filename.branch
```

and their merge base,

```
git show `git merge-base HEAD branch-to-merge`:filename  >filename.base
```

You'll merge them using whatever tool you want (e.g.)

```
meld filename.{HEAD,branch,base}
```

you'll stage that (`git add filename`), and then commit the merge (`git commit`).

Comment: Wondering the same thing Graham... I tried doing `git merge --no-commit branch` and it ended up merging it... What I'd like is to end up with 3 files, or 2 files. That I could use a diff and move over everything I want into that file.

Comment: If you want the original merge command to leave *everything* alone, to be done manually, you can call it as `git merge -s ours` to keep everything as it is in the current branch, but then it's up to you to ensure that changes in other files make it over.

Comment: @Steven; I think the idea is you ignore the merged file and use the HEAD and branch files i.e. the "two files" you're after are HEAD:filename and branch-to-merge:filename.

Comment: Git Gotcha: `git merge --no-commit --no-ff` will not commit anything at all, see @Brad-O answer below. You have to include `--no-ff`

Comment: I made a git alias from the above commands. It is hairy, but it works. You do need to have the config variable "merge.tool" set for it to work. Also, my version doesn't create a new file with ".base" appended; it just overwrites the file in the current branch. You call the alias as `git remerge <branch> <file path>`. You must be in the git root dir for it to work: 

`git config --global alias.remerge '!sh -c "git show HEAD:${2} > ${2}.HEAD; git show ${1}:${2} > ${2}.${1}; git show $(git merge-base HEAD ${1}):${2} > ${2}; $(git config --get merge.tool) ${2}.HEAD ${2} ${2}.${1};"'`

Comment: Does `git merge --no-commit --no-ff branch-to-merge` keep commit history of branch-to-merge?

Comment: @Kootoopas: yes

Answer (score 51):

From the branch you want to merge into:

```
git checkout -p branch_to_merge --
```

This won't checkout the branch_to_merge, but will let you interactively add hunks from the patch (diff).

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: This was very easy to use for interactive merging - thanks!

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: This command presents each "hunk" (differences in the files that are grouped close together) and an option of "yes" or "no" to use it or not.  Very useful.

Comment: For everything you've done on the branch and which is not on master, this assumes it should be deleted. That is not the smartest merge strategy.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum - hoping better to understand your warning. Doesn't -p actually compare what was done on each branch and show you the difference, no matter the origin?

Comment: @KayV Just don't see it only as interactively adding (c)hunks, see it just as well as interactively discarding changes in your working directory.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum - thanks for the response; I'm interested in understanding but still not following. Are you referring to changes that are not staged at the time you run the command?

Comment: @KayV I don't mean anything complicated. Just create a simple git test project for yourself. You'll be interactively asked if staged/committed stuff on that branch can be removed if it doesn't exist on the branch you're getting your patches from. It's perfectly reasonable and to be expected behavior, but might still catch someone by surprise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @AnnevanRossum - I actually use this method pretty frequently and have not run into the downside you mention. Naturally if I'm overlooking something I'd like to discover before it's a problem. Unfortunately the details of your warning are unclear to me - hence my questions. Can you describe the setup you recommend so I can see it myself?

Comment: This has been by far the best answer in my opinion, exactly what was initially asked: `An interactive merge approach for git`

Comment: It seems this is underrated answer.  First time using it on my part, and its beautifully does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: While it does what OP wants, it's not an actual merge, is it? If you use `git log --graph` you'll see just another commit rather than a merging of branches. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 45):

The easiest way is to do `git merge <other_branch` then `git mergetool` to graphically resolve the conflicts. See [#10935226](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935226/git-interactive-merge) for how to set up mergetool.

The hitch is, your changed file may fast-forward merge with with the older one. Then you have to get a bit more clever.

Novelocrat gives a great way to dig a bit deeper, but you will often have to change the initial command to `git merge --no-commit --no-ff <other_branch>` because --no-commit really means "Don't commit the merge...unless it's a fast-forward merge." It's a bit of a stinger for lots of folks trying to do exactly what you want.

Sometimes the least confusing way is not very stylish: check out the other branch in a different working copy, use your favorite merge tool to get the version you want in the directory you want, then commit it.

Comment: 10935226 is this question's number. What did you mean to write there?

Comment: The underlying problem (for me) is that even if there are no conflicts, often git will make wrong merge decisions, discarding stuff i wanted. So an interactive merge is useful.

Answer (score 40):

As per this gist, where temp could be an existing branch.

https://gist.github.com/katylava/564416

---

On master:

```
git checkout -b temp
```

On temp:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff refactor
```

… which stages everything, so:

```
git reset HEAD
```

Then begin adding the pieces you want:

```
git add --interactive
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to leave off 'head' in 'git reset head', but git reset worked fine.

Comment: A final `git commit` does not do a merge! – How do I finish the merge in the end?

Comment: @RobertSiemer  Maybe I guess you can do normal merge in the next steps:  git co master; git merge temp

Comment: The nice part is the `patch` option from `git add --interactive`, which lets you stage parts of a diff, as described in the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to do this is:

1. Checkout the branch with your changes
2. Create a new branch from that point
3. Reset your new branch to the commit you want to compare to and build upon.  The reset will be a "mixed" reset by default, meaning that it will not change the "working tree", i.e. the actual code files
4. At this point, my text editor (VSCode) shows me what is different between my current files and the commit I reset to.  I can edit the code to select which lines I want to commit.
   What this does is allow me to see everything my branch changed and confirm every line of code I will commit.  This is useful such as before merging my changes back into production.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/), [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), or any available diff/merge UI tool to do the work manually.  If you want to hook it into "git difftool", you can search online to find ways to make those tools work with git.