# git merge two branches line by line interactively

Tags: git, version-control, branch, diff, git-branch

I want to merge two branches, git thinks there is no conflict however it is. So I want to merge the two branches interactively line by line preferably with emacs ediff, however other tools should be ok.

I am really new to git, so please be verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merging in steps interactively will be done with the "--no-commit" option. (which does the merge but pretend it failed and not commits. Thus you have a chance to see and change result of merge)

Check out these links - they are more detailed and some also supply solution to the merge tool embedding.

GitHub:
[git selective merge](https://gist.github.com/katylava/564416)

Stack: scroll down here - there are like 3 solutions : 
[git-interactive-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935226/git-interactive-merge)