# How to list only the names of files that changed between two commits

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a bunch of commits in the repository. I want to see a list of files changed between two commits - from *SHA1* to *SHA2*.

What command should I use?

Comment: For a commit and its parent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git

Comment: You should change the question title...you don't want to list the file names that changed...you want to list the names of files that changed. Note that it is possible to change the names of files without changing their contents.

Answer (score 3592, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```

where you only need to include enough of the SHA hash to identify the commits. The order of the SHAs does not matter. The output (which includes the relative path, not just the file name) follows this format:

```
 dir 1/dir 2/filename.ext
 dir 3/dir 4/other filename.ext
```

You can also do, for example

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~10 HEAD~5
```

to see the differences between the tenth latest commit and the fifth latest (or so).

Comment: This works for git show as well. `git show --name-only SHA1`.

Comment: `git diff --name-status [TAG|SHA1]` shows what operations were done to the files too

Comment: you can also do:
    
    git diff --name-only HEAD@{3} HEAD@{0}

for the exact commits you want to compare.

Comment: @AugustLilleaas actually using show will only show the 2 specific commits, if you have commits between those 2 they will be left out

Comment: not what the OP asked, but you can also do:
`git log -p --name-only`

Comment: `--name-only` only shows the *files* that were changed.. now If I do `git diff SHA1 SHA2` I'll see all the code.. for large commits this can look really bad on the CLI.. is there a gui software (ie a diff tool like [diffmerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)) that can accept such a git command and visually display the diff?

Comment: never mind.. i just figured out that it can be done visually.. ie with tools like [sourcetree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview?_mid=8b90e14347096994af7257f4bfdf89e0&gclid=COrPx5jNrLsCFSYHwwodZAcAXQ) using diffmerge as a gui diff app.. you can simply select all the commits (including the one before the first commit, or else you won't see the changes of the first commit).. and it will aggregate all the diffs in a nice way.. pretty neat!

Comment: this will show only the file name not the changes in the files, check my response below: `git diff --word-diff SHA1 SHA2`

Comment: As noted below, `git diff --name-status` doesn't seem to want to show added files.  @sschuberth pointed out `git show`, which does seem to work properly for me:  `git show --pretty=format: --name-status`.   Just doing `git show --name-status` gives a bit more info, but still nice and dense... that will be my new goto command ;)

Comment: That's pretty cool, how can you filter by author then like you do with `git log --author`?

Comment: `git diff --name-only HEAD^` for what changed in the most recent commit

Comment: By the way, just like `git status` shows a list of modified files, you can do `git diff --name-only` to get the same list without the *modified:* prefix. Useful if you want to pipe the output for processing.

Comment: Is there some way to colorize this output?

Comment: I was looking into this solution in order to generate a list of files to be processed by a linter, so I had to filter out deleted files and broken links. This is what I'm using now: `git --no-pager diff --name-only --diff-filter=db HEAD`. As per the docs: _"...these upper-case letters can be downcased to exclude. E.g.  --diff-filter=ad excludes added and deleted paths..."_

Answer (score 585):

```
git diff --name-status [SHA1 [SHA2]]
```

is like --name-only, except you get a simple prefix telling you what happened to the file (modified, deleted, added...)

```
git log --name-status --oneline [SHA1..SHA2]
```

is similar, but commits are listed after the commit message, so you can see when a file was changed.

- if you're interested in just what happened to certain files/folders you can append  `-- <filename> [<filename>...]` to the `git log` version.
- if you want to see what happened for a single commit, call it SHA1, then do
  `git log --name-status --oneline [SHA1^..SHA1]`

File status flags:

| Flag | Name | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `M` | modified | File has been modified |
| `C` | copy-edit | File has been copied and modified |
| `R` | rename-edit | File has been renamed and modified |
| `A` | added | File has been added |
| `D` | deleted | File has been deleted |
| `U` | unmerged | File has conflicts after a merge |

Comment: I happen to say git diff --name-status and it did give the 'added file'.

Comment: For git log, it needs to have two dots between the SHAs, like SHA1..SHA2, and the second SHA isn't optional, so it should look like this: git log --name-status --oneline [SHA1..SHA2]

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain files/certain file types?

Comment: The `--relative[=<path>]` option may help you, I'm not sure. Otherwise there's always `| erep -v '(.tmp|.foo|.dontwant)$'` ...

Comment: @artfulrobot did you mean `egrep`?

Comment: @DavidMoles yes I did, but I can't edit the comment now!

Comment: @artfulrobot  well, now it's documented at least

Answer (score 159):

It seems that no one has mentioned the switch `--stat`:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD~5 HEAD
 .../java/org/apache/calcite/rex/RexSimplify.java   | 50 +++++++++++++++++-----
 .../apache/calcite/sql/fun/SqlTrimFunction.java    |  2 +-
 .../apache/calcite/sql2rel/SqlToRelConverter.java  | 16 +++++++
 .../org/apache/calcite/util/SaffronProperties.java | 19 ++++----
 .../org/apache/calcite/test/RexProgramTest.java    | 24 +++++++++++
 .../apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.java |  8 ++++
 .../apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.xml  | 15 +++++++
 pom.xml                                            |  2 +-
 .../apache/calcite/adapter/spark/SparkRules.java   |  7 +--
 9 files changed, 117 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
```

There are also `--numstat`

```
$ git diff --numstat HEAD~5 HEAD
40      10      core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/rex/RexSimplify.java
1       1       core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/fun/SqlTrimFunction.java
16      0       core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql2rel/SqlToRelConverter.java
8       11      core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/util/SaffronProperties.java
24      0       core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/RexProgramTest.java
8       0       core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.java
15      0       core/src/test/resources/org/apache/calcite/test/SqlToRelConverterTest.xml
1       1       pom.xml
4       3       spark/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/adapter/spark/SparkRules.java
```

and `--shortstat`

```
$ git diff --shortstat HEAD~5 HEAD
9 files changed, 117 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
```

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but this is super useful and gives you a little extra info. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed this is a more useful answer since it contains the diff stats.

Answer (score 79):

But for seeing the files changed between your branch and its common ancestor with another branch (say origin/master):

```
git diff --name-only `git merge-base origin/master HEAD`
```

Comment: This was really useful! I wish I could simply say `git diffstatus master` or similar, that triggers the above.

Comment: Or `git show --pretty=format: --name-only origin/master..`.

Comment: You might not be able to make it a git alias, but you can definitely put it into your .bashrc.

Comment: Or even simpler: `git diff --name-only HEAD...master` (note the three dots). For a detailed explanation, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/2063031).

Comment: Looks like mostly correct answer! Simple `git diff --name-only master..branch` doesn't correspond to github PR list. This way more precise. But anyway I have 173 chaned files vs 171 in github PR. (without `merge-base` I have 228 vs 171)

Comment: You may use the git flag `--merge-base` to achieve the same result without the need of executing 2 commands like so: `git diff --name-only --merge-base origin/master`.   Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 39):

The biggest issue with every previous answer is that you get fed into a pager which is extremely annoying if you want to use the information you're trying to get out of the repository.
Especially if you're a developer that would rather be learning the business logic of the application your supposed to be developing instead of learning vim commands.

Using --no-pager solves that issue.

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only sha1 sha2
```

Comment: The `--no-pager` is really key. Thanks for standing out.

Comment: An alternative to the `--no-pager` option is simply to pipe to `cat` (though you do lose the colour): `git diff --name-only sha1 sha2 | cat`

Comment: Set once and for all in git config: `core.pager=less -+X -F` - screen-shorter output will go in the console, long output (requiring scrolling) will show up in the pager, indispensable.

Answer (score 33):

To supplement @artfulrobot's answer, if you want to show changed files between two branches:

```
git diff --name-status mybranch..myotherbranch
```

Be careful on precedence. If you place the newer branch first then it would show files as deleted rather than added.

Adding a `grep` can refine things further:

```
git diff --name-status mybranch..myotherbranch | grep "A\t"
```

That will then show only files added in `myotherbranch`.

Comment: Regexes are nice an can indeed do almost anything. In this case, though, there's also `--diff-filter` which gives this functionality natively, which means less chance of incorrect results (e.g. false positives)

Comment: this won't work if there are `"A\t"` in the file names. You need `grep "^A\t"`

Answer (score 20):

Also note, if you just want to see the changed files between the last commit and the one before it, this works fine:

```
git show --name-only
```

Comment: simple and easy to remember. It should have get a lot more upvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Add the below alias to your `~/.bash_profile` file, and then run `source ~/.bash_profile`; now anytime you need to see the updated files in the last commit, run, `showfiles` from your git repository.

```
alias showfiles='git show --pretty="format:" --name-only'
```

Comment: Or `git config --global alias.showfiles 'show --pretty="format:" --name-only'` to make `git showfiles`.

Answer (score 9):

The following works well for me:

```
git show --name-only --format=tformat: SHA1..SHA2
```

It can also be used with a single commit:

```
git show --name-only --format=tformat: SHA1
```

which is handy for use in [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) where you are provided with a *list* of changeset SHA hash values, and want to iterate over them to see which files have been changed.

This is similar to a couple of the previous answers, but using `tformat:` rather than `format:` removes the separator space between commits.

Answer (score 7):

This will show the changes in files:

```
git diff --word-diff SHA1 SHA2
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for someone who needs to focus only on Java files, this is my solution:

```
 git diff --name-status SHA1 SHA2 | grep '\.java$'
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking for the list of changed files, including staged files

```
git diff HEAD --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AMCR

git diff HEAD --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AMCR sha-1 sha-2
```

Remove `--relative` if you want absolute paths.

Comment: `diff-filter=...` was what I was searching

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
git log --pretty=oneline > C:\filename.log
```

which will log only a oneline (`--pretty=oneline`) that's the name of the changed file. It will also log all the details to your output file.

Comment: `git log --pretty=oneline` gives me only the SHA and the commit message using git 2.10.1

Comment: On Windows? In what context?

Answer (score 3):

Based on `git diff --name-status` I wrote the [git-diffview](https://github.com/opicbernard/git-diffview) Git extension that renders a hierarchical tree view of what changed between two paths.

Answer (score 1):

As artfulrobot said in his answer:

```
git diff --name-status [SHA1 [SHA2]]
```

My example:

```
git diff --name-status 78a09k12067c24d8f117886c4723ccf111af4997 
4b95d595812211553070046bf2ebd807c0862cca
M       views/layouts/default.ctp
M       webroot/css/theme.css
A       webroot/img/theme/logo.png
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the previous answers.