# Can I make 'git diff' only display the line numbers AND changed file names?

Tags: git, git-diff

**This question calls for "line numbers". If you do not care about line numbers in the output, [see this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1552340/124486).**

---

Basically, I don't want to see the changed content, just the file names and line numbers.

Comment: I'm curious, are line numbers really useful without code? Or do you want the number of lines changed?

Comment: well, not particularly, but I need it to bookmark where I have changed my code.

Comment: One usage of this would be to combine the info with a code coverage report, to assess whether the new or modified code in a commit is covered by tests

Comment: @AntonyG I found this question while trying to build a utility that does exactly the same thing (coverage vs changed lines). Did you manage to build the report? If so, did you publish it anywhere?

Comment: @AndrewNewdigate it would be a cool tool but I never built it. I was doing some other kind of code coverage results processing when I came across this question, but couldn't justify the time required to implement my suggestion

Comment: So, you don't want to know what files have had their names changed? The question is ambiguous :/

Comment: A modern and a short answer today could be e.g. `git diff master --numstat` or `git diff master --compact-summary`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Note: if you're **just looking for the names** of changed files (**without** the **line numbers** for lines that were changed), see [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13851260/1256452).

---

There's no built-in option for this (and I don't think it's all that useful either), but it *is* possible to do this in Git, with the help of an "external diff" script.

Here's a pretty crappy one; it will be up to you to fix up the output the way you would like it.

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# run this with:
#    GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=<name of script> git diff ...
#
case $# in
1) "unmerged file $@, can't show you line numbers"; exit 1;;
7) ;;
*) echo "I don't know what to do, help!"; exit 1;;
esac

path=$1
old_file=$2
old_hex=$3
old_mode=$4
new_file=$5
new_hex=$6
new_mode=$7

printf '%s: ' $path
diff $old_file $new_file | grep -v '^[<>-]'
```

For details on "external diff", see the description of `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` on the [Git manual page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html) (around line 700, pretty close to the end).

Comment: Thanks. I actually have written a similar script, after having been confirmed that there is no built-in options for this, :)

Comment: Piping to `| grep -o '^[0-9]*'` gives you just numbers, assuming you don't care about the right-hand side.

Comment: @DylanYoung yes; to limit the files shown, add `--diff-filter=...` where the `...` part is the kind of changes you want to see: `M` for modified, `A` for added, `D` for deleted, and others per the `git diff` documentation.

Comment: @Sventies: that's not what the OP asked for, as I note at the top of my answer. He does not want the *names* of the files alone. He wants the *names **with line numbers***.

Comment: Fair enough @torek :)

Answer (score 977):

You can use this command to see the changed file names, but not with line numbers:

```
git diff --name-only
```

Go forth and diff!

Comment: This is possible the answer most people are looking for when they view this page (it was for me). However, it doesn't answer the original question, which specifically mentions line numbers.

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer as it only solves half the problem- you still need to output which lines (for each file) that were changed.

Comment: That's it! I was looking for this switch exactly!

Comment: Why not use "git status"? It also tells you the untracked files.

Comment: @JimmyPaul because sometimes you already have commited. For example you need to list changed file between master and your current advanced branch `git diff --name-only master..HEAD`

Comment: So easy. Why this answer was not marked as best. 
It can confuse people who come and not read answers after the one marked as best.

Comment: @PieterMüller  I agree with you. But that's usually how it works. When you ask more than a question in one go, you usually don't get answer for all of them.

Comment: Does this require a particular version of `git`? It's not working for me, passing a hash to diff against (it just spits back the command usage instructions)... This alternative worked for me though: `git diff [hash] | grep diff`

Comment: @PieterMüller I do agree this is problematic as it's what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 93):

Line numbers as in number of changed lines or the actual line numbers containing the changes? If you want the number of changed lines, use `git diff --stat`. This gives you a display like this:

```
[me@somehost:~/newsite:master]> git diff --stat
 whatever/views/gallery.py |    8 ++++++++
 1 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

There is no option to get the line numbers of the changes themselves.

Comment: I was thinking the actual line numbers. Thanks though.

Comment: I somehow doubt he wants a GUI tool for this.

Answer (score 52):

Use:

```
git diff master --compact-summary
```

The output is:

```sh
 src/app/components/common/sidebar/toolbar/toolbar.component.html   |  2 +-
 src/app/components/common/sidebar/toolbar/toolbar.component.scss   |  2 --
```

This is exactly what you need. The same format as when you are making a commit or pulling new commits from the remote.

PS: It's weird that nobody answered this way.

Comment: That wasn't specified. It works from 2.18 released year ago.

Comment: Perfect. This worked for me and the response is perfect.

Answer (score 25):

**1)** My favorite:

```
git diff --name-status
```

Prepends file status, e.g.:

```
A   new_file.txt
M   modified_file.txt 
D   deleted_file.txt
```

**2)** If you want statistics, then:

```
git diff --stat
```

will show something like:

```
new_file.txt         |  50 +
modified_file.txt    | 100 +-
deleted_file         |  40 -
```

**3)** Finally, if you really want only the filenames:

```
git diff --name-only
```

Will simply show:

```
new_file.txt
modified_file.txt
deleted_file
```

Answer (score 5):

Shows the file names and amount/nubmer of lines that changed in each file between now and the specified commit:

```
git diff --stat <commit-hash>
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, this filters the Git output to the files and changed line numbers:

`(git diff -p --stat) | findstr "@@ --git"`

```
diff --git a/dir1/dir2/file.cpp b/dir1/dir2/file.cpp
@@ -47,6 +47,7 @@ <some function name>
@@ -97,7 +98,7 @@ <another functon name>
```

To extract the files and the changed lines from that is a bit more work:

`for /f "tokens=3,4* delims=-+ " %f in ('^(git diff -p --stat .^) ^| findstr ^"@@ --git^"') do @echo %f`

```
a/dir1/dir2/file.cpp
47,7
98,7
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest output, i.e. file names/paths only, comes with

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r
```

Answer (score 0):

On `git version 2.17.1`, **there isn't a built-in flag** to achieve this purpose.

Here's an example command to filter out the filename and line numbers from an unified diff:

```
git diff --unified=0 | grep -Po '^diff --cc \K.*|^@@@( -[0-9]+,[0-9]+){2} \+\K[0-9]+(?=(,[0-9]+)? @@@)' | paste -s -d':'
```

For example, the unified diff:

```
$ git diff --unified=0
diff --cc foobar
index b436f31,df63c58..0000000
--- a/foobar
+++ b/foobar
@@@ -1,2 -1,2 +1,6 @@@ Line abov
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +bar
++=======
+ foo
++>>>>>>> Commit message
```

Will result in:

```
❯ git diff --unified=0 | grep -Po '^diff --cc \K.*|^@@@( -[0-9]+,[0-9]+){2} \+\K[0-9]+(?=(,[0-9]+)? @@@)' | paste -s -d':'
foobar:1
```

To match the output of commands in common grep match results:

```
$ git diff --unified=0 | grep -Po '^diff --cc \K.*|^@@@( -[0-9]+,[0-9]+){2} \+\K[0-9]+(?=(,[0-9]+)? )| @@@.*' | sed -e '0~3{s/ @@@[ ]\?//}' | sed '2~3 s/$/\n1/g' | sed "N;N;N;s/\n/:/g"
foobar:1:1:Line abov
```

1. `grep -Po '^diff --cc \K.*|^@@@( -[0-9]+,[0-9]+){2} \+\K[0-9]+(?=(,[0-9]+)? )`: Match filename from `diff --cc <filename>` OR Match line number from `@@@ <from-file-range> <from-file-range> <to-file-range>` OR Match remaining text after `@@@`.
2. `sed -e '0~3{s/ @@@[ ]\?//}'`: Remove `@@@[ ]\?` from every 3rd line to get the optional 1 line context before `++<<<<<<< HEAD`.
3. `sed '2~3 s/$/\n1/g'`: Add `\n1` every 3 lines between the 2nd and 3rd line for the column number.
4. `sed "N;N;N;s/\n/:/g"`: Join every 3 lines with a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `grep` as a naive solution.

```
$ git diff | grep -A2 -- '---'
```

An output example:

```
--- a/fileA.txt
+++ b/fileA.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,132 @@
--
--- a/B/fileC.txt
+++ b/B/fileC.txt
@@ -33663,3 +33663,68800 @@ word_38077.png,Latin
--
--- a/D/fileE.txt
+++ b/D/fileE.txt
@@ -17998,3 +17998,84465 @@ word_23979.png,Latin
--
--- a/F
+++ b/F
@@ -1 +1 @@
```

Maybe you can see the colored output. It helps you to read the output easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
git dif | grep -B <number of before lines to show> <regex>
```

In my case, I tried to search for where I had put a debug statement in the many files. I needed to see which file already got this debug statement like this:

```
git diff | grep -B 5 dd\(
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but here's one line of bash:

```
git diff --unified=0 HEAD~1..HEAD | grep -Po '(^diff --git [a-zA-Z/._]*|^@@.*@@)' | while read l; do if [[ -n ${l##@@*} ]]; then f=${l#*/}; else echo "$f:${l##@@ }" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '-'; fi; done
```

Explanation:

1. `git diff --unified=0 HEAD~1..HEAD`

Retrieves the commit info from Git

2. `grep -Po '(^diff --git [a-zA-Z/._]*|^@@.*@@)'`

Builds on a prior answer and filters down to lines containing
filenames and line numbers

3. Expanding the one-liner into multiple lines for readability's sake:

```
while read line; do
  if [[ -n ${line##@@*} ]]; then
    # Grabs filename from this pattern: "diff --git a/....."
    filename=${line#*/};
  else
    # Grabs line number from this patterns: "@@ -<line> +<line> @@"
    echo"$filename:${line##@@ }" | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '-';
  fi;
done
```

String parsing that converts into expected output:

```
file/name1.txt:34
file/name2.txt:98
file/name2.txt:101
file/name3.txt:2
```