# GIT list of new/modified/deleted files

Tags: git, file, list, diff

Is there a way to get the list of all new/deleted/modified directories/files in a local/remote repository with relation to each other in Git?

Comment: `git status` seems to do that.

Comment: This question is broad and not very clear -- with the result that the following answers cover quite different scenarios and use cases. Unfortunately, it's too late to make the question more specific as this would invalidate some of the (good) answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list only the names of files that changed between two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-only-the-names-of-files-that-changed-between-two-commits)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The best way to list these file is using `git status --porcelain`.

For example:

```
git status --porcelain | awk 'match($1, "D"){print $2}'
```

shows you the tracked files which have been deleted from the local copy. You can delete all these files by appending an appropriate command to the pipe:

```
git status --porcelain | awk 'match($1, "D"){print $2}' | xargs git rm
```

Answer (score 39):

I'm not sure what you mean by with respect to each other, but if you want an individual listing (e.g. all modified files) you can use `git ls-files` with the right flags (for modified files it's `-m`). If you want all of this info at once, you can use `git status --porcelain` to get a script-parsable output of the status.

Comment: Git status doesn't list the new directories/files that has been added to remote repo. Does it ?

Comment: @alertjean: What do you mean by "new"? Are they untracked? Are they added but not committed? What are they?

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for.  Now I can do e.g. `geany $(git ls-files -m)`

Answer (score 28):

To get just file names and status of the currently changed files you can simply:

`git diff --name-status`

You will get the bare output like this:

```
M       a.txt
M       b.txt
```

Now, pipe the output to `cut` to extract the second column:

`git diff --name-status | cut -f2`

Then you'll have just the file names:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Comment: cut : The term 'cut' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:26

Comment: This example was created assuming you have a linux bash available. On windows, depending on your version, you'll need to install "Windows subsystem for Linux" on Windows 10 or something like Cygwin on previous windows versions.

Comment: Wouldn't `git diff --name-only` do the same thing as `cut -f2`?

Comment: What is this magical `cut` command and why didn't I know about it sooner? Nice!

Comment: `git diff` does not list new files, just modified and deleted ones while `git status --porcelain` does. And for `cut`, maybe it was not the case at this time, but when installing Git you should have Git Bash installed with it, then no need to install "Windows subsystem for Linux", just run command on a Git Bash terminal.

Comment: @PaulSturm check out "The Linux Command Line" by Shotts; you may have many more of those magical moments, most likely.

Answer (score 20):

One way to do this is with the `whatchanged` command:

```
$ git whatchanged
```

This shows which files changed for each commit in the tree and can be used to look at specifics as well. Take a look at `git help whatchanged`

Comment: I see more than simple list of file names

Comment: I wanted to see list of files changed since beginning of project. This command helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Use the dry-run (-n) option of `git add`:

`git add -A -n`

Comment: yup, thats the one I wanted!

Comment: exactly what I wanted too. simple and shows me what files are going to be pushed.

Comment: Or `git add -un` to omit untracked files.

Answer (score 13):

What you probably want is something like:

```
git fetch     # update what you know about the remote repo
git diff --name-status master origin/master
```

But it's pretty difficult to tell exactly what branches you want to diff from your question.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I needed the list of all new/modified/untracked files. The below command did the trick:

```sh
git status --porcelain | cut -c 1-3 --complement
```

The `cut -c 1-3 --complement` part is for removing the three initial status characters so that I could run arbitrary scripts with `xargs` against the files. For instance, run eslint against all new/changed JavaScript files (in a nodejs repo):

```sh
git status --porcelain | cut -c 1-3 --complement | egrep .js$ | xargs npm run lint -- --fix
```

Answer (score 2):

use with command `--name-status`

example with tags:

```
git diff v1.0.1 v1.0.2 --name-status
```

example with commits:

```
git diff b79810fc4d be69e41d1c --name-status
```

it will list all the updated files with their statuses:
`M` - modified
`D` - deleted
`A` - added

Answer (score 2):

`git diff --name-only` does the work, but it shows the tracked files only. In order to include the new files, you may (temporary) add all files with `git add .` and now the `git diff --cached --name-only` should list all changed files. After that, you may `git restore --staged .` to un-stage all files.

Comment: is there really no other way to do this? this is annoying if you've partially staged something

Comment: @phil294, I think, there are. In this thread, for example, there are answers that mention about the `--porcelian` option. I simply suggested yet another way. If you'd use it frequently, you may wrap it into a script or set up as a user git command for your convenience.

Comment: @phil294, as an addition: I personally faced with need to get such a list of changed/added files very rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Do `git diff` and you will see all the files changed and the details of what changed in those files

Answer (score 0):

To git all files that your are **added, modified deleted and new files** you use two commands
`git ls-files -o` to get all new files and `git checkout` for get delete files , modified files and added files

> `git ls-files -o && git checkout`

How I know deleted, modified , deleted files and new files if you see before the file

- A   `this is added file to git`
- D   `this is deleted file`
- M  `this is Modified file`
- `Nothing before the file this is a new file`

see this gif image
[image: get added, deleted, modified and new files in git]