# How to find out the list of files being change between 2 SHA?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: show all changed files between two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/git-show-all-changed-files-between-two-commits)

How can I get a list of files being committed/added between 2 SHA (I get the SHA using 'git log')?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff  --name-only SHA1 SHA2
```