# Git - How can I list all files changed on the master branch between two times?

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I'd like to find out all the files that have been modified on the master branch (or any one branch for that matter) between two dates.

I understand, from this post ([How to list the file names only that changed between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/git-show-all-changed-files-between-two-commits)) that I can use

`git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2`

but I don't know, a priori, what the SHA's are between today and yesterday. Especially when there can be more than one commit on a day.

To be more precise, I would like to know the list of files changed on the master git repo between Today at 12:01 AM and yesterday at 12:01 AM.

Is this possible? I used to be able to do this in CVS with `cvs diff -D "1 days ago"`.

Comment: this can't be correct information as you may have merges which happened with in this period, but commits was some time ago.

Comment: So a merge would not count a file to be listed when doing `git diff`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git has a facility for using the reflog to get the position a name was at an arbitrary amount of time ago.

```
git diff --name-only master@{1 day ago} master
```

This will give you the difference between where `master` was exactly one day prior to now, and where master is now.

Comment: Had to add quotes around `1 day ago` but worked! Thanks.

Comment: That gives me `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master@': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`