# List out all the files that I have pushed to the remote Git repo

Tags: git, git-diff

How do I list out all the files that I have pushed in my last push to a remote Git repository?

I have a project and have modified only few files and `add, commit and push` it to the remote. Now how do I see the list of files I have pushed to remote?

Should it have something to do with last commit ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: show all changed files between two commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/git-show-all-changed-files-between-two-commits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your remote-tracking branches and their reflog to see what changes you have pushed. For example, if you pushed code to `origin/master`, you can list all the files that you changed with the following:

```bash
git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status
```

The syntax basically says to take the difference between `origin/master@{1}`, i.e. `origin/master` at its 1st previous position, and the current state of `origin/master`, as last known by your local repo.