# Identifying all files that have changed since my last commit *to that file*

Tags: git

I'm working on a Git project where one of my roles is to be aware of and review/edit all changes to a part of a project, which is a bit scattered around the codebase.  The team is making lots of changes all over the codebase, and I'd like to focus my review to the parts I need, but not worry about reviewing the parts that haven't changed since my last commit there (since I'd obviously have reviewed that).

Now, I don't know *all* of git's commands, but I don't think there's one that will solve all of this itself.  So, I was planning to assemble a script that roughly did:

- Find all the files in the repository
- Find my last commit to that file

  - Determine if the file changed since the identified commit
  - If so, output the filename, date/time of my commit, and date/time/owner of the latest commit.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?  Am I on the right track?  Am I missing a command or existing script that would handle this, or at least simplify it?

Note: I've made many commits to this project scattered across many files.  There's not a single commit I could compare to current that would cover all the files, and I've made unrelated commits to the same project, so I can't just check what has changed since my last commit to the repository :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show all changed files between two Git commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/show-all-changed-files-between-two-git-commits)

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with a pre-receive hook that rejected any changes to that file that weren't coming from you.  Trying to manage things after the fact has never been manageable in my experience.