# How to get list of changed files in Git post-receive hook?

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I need to get a list of changed files in server-side hook.  Example:

```
Local commit 1:

M test.txt
M test2.txt

Local commit 2:

M test.txt
A test3.txt
```

Both commits get pushed to the server (bare repo).  I need to loop through the list of files AND post each of them through curl elsewhere:

```
M test.txt
M test2.txt
A test3.txt
```

I'm struggling to find the documentation to achieve this. I know the revisions are spit out to stdin.  How do I actually loop through the pushed files, and reference them for a curl upload (this seems difficult since it's a bare repo)?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  echo $oldrev
  echo $newrev
  echo $refname
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-the-file-names-only-that-changed-between-two-commits

Comment: @AndrewC git diff won't work on a bare repository since there's no working directory. EDIT: I stand corrected, apparently it does work when specifying the references explicitly

Comment: It will when you provide it two SHAs.

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks for the link.  This resolves looping through the pushed files.  As for the second part, do you have any idea how to access the physical file / file bytes on the bare repository in order to post these through curl?  I only need to do a read on the bytes.

Comment: `git show` or `git cat-file` ?