# Git find stale files

Tags: git

I've started maintaining a large, unwieldy, repo with a lot of outdated code that could be deprecated or removed. So, I want to find files that have not been changed since a specific commit so that I can go through and check if they're still necessary.

I can find files in my repo that [**have** changed since a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-the-file-names-only-that-changed-between-two-commits) via:

```
git diff --name-only SHA
```

But how do I find files that **have not** been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell utility [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) is seriously under-appreciated.

```
$ git diff --name-only $SHA | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort > /tmp/A
$ git ls-tree -r --full-tree --name-only HEAD | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort > /tmp/B
$ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 comm -13 /tmp/A /tmp/B
```

will produce the list you want, by subtracting the set of all changed files from the set of all files.  (It's a little finicky, though, hence all the `LC_ALL` overrides.  If you get error messages about `C.UTF-8` try just `C` instead.)

Comment: Ah, comm! Rad. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of getting the end result you need, though it doesn't specifically answer your question of finding unchanged files.

The quick way would be to get a copy of all the files which have changed between the hash and the head:

```
cp -p --parents `git diff --name-only $3 $4` /path/to/output
```

You can then initiate your git repository in that folder and force a commit with those files.  That should remove all the old files and leave you with only the changed ones.

Alternatively, do as above and use a directory comparison tool like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) which will let you know which files exist in the repository, but not in the directory of updated files.  You can then delete the files from the repository.