# Git - List all changed files during staging

Tags: git

I've been looking for a way to get all the changed files in a repository *during the staging process* (uncommitted) in a list, but [all I can find is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit) [how to do it between 2 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-the-file-names-only-that-changed-between-two-commits).

Doing `git status` shows a list of modified files, but I need to get the list in a format that I can parse easily with a script.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command mentioned above and then, cut, sed it to fetch only file name.

```
git status -s --porcelain | cut -c4-
```

```
git status -s --porcelain | sed -e 's!.*/!!'
```

if you wish to track unstaged files.

```
git status -uno
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a good one, because it leads you into the first big secret of Git's index: that the index acts as a storage area for *all the files that will be in the next commit*.

In other words, you have a *current commit* (aka `HEAD`), and a work-tree (which you can just look at).  But you have this invisible area, the *staging area* or *index* or *cache* (it has three names), that *also* has copies of every file.

Git lets you compare any of these:

- any two commits: `git diff commit1 commit2`;
- the index and the work-tree: `git diff` (this is what you *can stage* for a commit);
- any commit and the work-tree: `git diff commit`, e.g., `git diff HEAD`—but this *ignores* the staging area; and last, perhaps what you want:
- any commit and the staging area: `git diff --cached commit`, e.g., `git diff --cached HEAD`.  If you omit the *`commit`*, it defaults to `HEAD`, so `git diff --cached` gets what you want here.

Your own answer mentions `git status --short` (or `-s`).  This actually runs *two* `git diff` commands internally.  That's why there are two columns for each status letter, and two question-marks for untracked files: the first column shows the result of comparing `HEAD` to the staging-area/cache/index, and the second shows the result of comparing the staging-area/cache/index to the work-tree.

If you have modified file `changed/file/1` but have *not yet* copied it *to* the staging area, the version of the file in the `HEAD` commit matches the version of the file in the staging area.  So the first column's status is blank (no change).  The copy of the file in the work-tree is different, so its column gets an `M`.

If you `git add changed/file/1`, this copies it from the work-tree to the staging-area, overwriting the version that matches the `HEAD` commit.  Now `git status -s` sees that the first comparison shows "modified" and the second shows "the same", so the `M` goes in the *first* column and the *second* column is blank.

You can modify the file in the work-tree yet again, and run `git status -s`, and this time you will get *two* `M`s: one says that `HEAD` and index/staging-area differ, and the other says that index/staging-area differs from work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

While I was researching this question I decided to look at the help page for `git status` and found this:

```
-s, --short
       Give the output in the short-format.

--porcelain[=<version>]
       Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user
       configuration. See below for details.
```

Using `git status -s --porcelain` will give the list below:

```
 M changed/file/1
 M changed/file/2
 M changed/file/3
?? untracked/
?? untrackedfile.txt
?? untracked/folder/2
?? other/untracked/folder
```

I also tried this on a repository with no untracked files, and the space in front of the `M` still remains.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff --cached` shows staged hunks.

`git diff --cached --name-only` list staged files.

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-files -c` to list all the staged files, `-d` for deleted files, `-m` for modified, and `-i` for ignored, and `-o` for others (untracked).

[More about git-ls-files](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)