# How only commited changes should go to production using jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, deployment, gitlab

I committed few changes to GIT, Only these changes should deploy to production by using jenkins.

Comment: Could you please tell, what you are building and how you deploy?

Comment: @Michael I have some 100 files in my GIT and i changed only 2 files out of that so now i want to deploy only those 2 files to production not remaining 98 files.. I'm building through the jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could build some script using `git diff` or `git log` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552353/437621) to get a list of changed files and then iterate through it to upload or delete changed files.