# How to list only file names changed by a user between two commits?

Tags: git

[How to list only the file names that changed between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-only-the-file-names-that-changed-between-two-commits)

```
$git diff 518be77..24a893b --name-only
```

Question> How can I get the list of file names that have been changed by a user(i.e. Tom)?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$git diff 518be77..24a893b --name-only --author=Tom
```

Also the following command can list all modified files by the user but I have to manually find those two commits.

```
$ git log --author=Tom --name-only --oneline
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --author=Tom --format='' --name-only HEAD~5.. | sort -u
```

`--format=''` prevents any output from `git log` except for file names; `git log` lists changed files in all commits by the author and there're probably many duplicates; `sort -u` handles those duplicates.

Comment: where do I input those two commits hashes?

Comment: You can replace HEAD~5 with <shaid>..<shaid>

Comment: In the `git log` arguments. First debug by looking at commits (`git log --author=Tom <shaid1>..<shaid2>`), then add the rest.

Comment: I tried the following command `git log --author=Tom --format='' --name-only 518be77..24a893b |sort -u`. In my git result, I still see many submit comments such as 'commit 3881432f56d8ed24c8aa04937864c22be71747fe' or 'Date:   Fri Jun 21 14:34:31 2019 -0500' etc. git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: I found the solution:

`git log --author=Tom --oneline --pretty="format:" --name-only 518be77..24a893b  | awk 'NF' | sort -u`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
git diff --author="Name of user" HEAD~5 --numstat
```

Comment: I don't see option `--author` in [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) docs.

Comment: That was a typo, should've been git log. But I see you've answered it below.