# Show list of all files changed/added/removed in the last x commits

Tags: git

I want to list all files changed in the recent X commits.

I tried:

```
git log --name-status -10
```

But it also logs additional information like commit id, author, date etc. I only need the filename. Is there a command to achieve this?

EDIT:

This edit should explain why my question is not a duplicate of "How to list only the file names that changed between two commits?" as the user phd claims.

I don't think that I have to explain it, it should be obvious that these are two entirely different questions. I asked how to create a list of the last x commits, while the "duplicate" asks about a list of commits between commit A and B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list only the file names that changed between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-only-the-file-names-that-changed-between-two-commits)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+changed+files

Comment: @phd, how is this a duplicate of "How to list only the file names that changed between two commits?" ??? Explain

Comment: @Black I'd have to side with phd on this one. It's a very similar need. Name one relevant difference between your question and the one phd linked. There are nuances, yes, but the analysis and solution are nearly identical.

Comment: @Black You asked "all files changed in the recent X commits" then "I only need the filename". What did I miss? (and to be clear, I'm not calling out your question as bad in any way, that's why I answered, it's a *good* question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way would be to

```
git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only -10 | sort -u
```

`| sort -u` helps with sorting and getting rid of doubles, while `--name-only` outputs the file list *without* status letters.

Comment: How is this better than using `git diff`?

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister It's *not* better, your diff proposal is better for a number of things, I tend to use it myself often. But if I got the question right, this solution is closer to what OP wanted because he just wants a filenames list. No?

Comment: `git diff --name-only` will do exactly that and you get to skip the piping through `sort -u` as it will not contain any duplicates in there. :-)  It will not contain the actual changes, only the files touched between the compared revisions.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I agree, `git diff --name-only` does the job indeed, my remarks were only adressing the statuses and stats part. And I get how OP's self-answer can have influenced the way to look at his question, I think I overlooked that.

Comment: No worries.  I was more interested in making sure you knew that `git diff --name-only` actually does the job and doesn't need any external commands to get it done. 
:-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister To be honest, when I first read your answer I was a bit puzzled but tried it and indeed it allows to skip the sorting part, it's great :-)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `git diff` here:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~10.. --
```

On one of the tags in the Python repo, this produced:

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~10.. --
Doc/library/http.client.rst
Doc/library/tkinter.rst
Include/patchlevel.h
Lib/http/client.py
Lib/ssl.py
Lib/test/libregrtest/setup.py
Lib/test/test_httplib.py
Lib/test/test_ssl.py
Lib/test/test_syntax.py
Mac/BuildScript/resources/ReadMe.rtf
Mac/BuildScript/resources/Welcome.rtf
Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc1.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc2.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Core and Builtins/2019-06-22-12-45-20.bpo-24214.hIiHeD.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-02-03-19-13-08.bpo-32627.b68f64.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-06-27-13-27-02.bpo-37428._wcwUd.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-06-27-20-33-50.bpo-37437.du39_A.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Windows/2019-06-18-09-05-08.bpo-35360.tdqSmo.rst
Misc/NEWS.d/next/Windows/2019-06-28-08-09-08.bpo-37369.1iVpxq.rst
Modules/expat/expat_external.h
Python/compile.c
Python/peephole.c
README.rst
configure
configure.ac
```

If you want the status, you can use the `--name-status` option with `diff` too:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~10.. --
```

Here the example above with the `--name-status` option:

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~10.. --
M   Doc/library/http.client.rst
M   Doc/library/tkinter.rst
M   Include/patchlevel.h
M   Lib/http/client.py
M   Lib/ssl.py
M   Lib/test/libregrtest/setup.py
M   Lib/test/test_httplib.py
M   Lib/test/test_ssl.py
M   Lib/test/test_syntax.py
M   Mac/BuildScript/resources/ReadMe.rtf
M   Mac/BuildScript/resources/Welcome.rtf
A   Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4.rst
M   Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc1.rst
A   Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc2.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Core and Builtins/2019-06-22-12-45-20.bpo-24214.hIiHeD.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-02-03-19-13-08.bpo-32627.b68f64.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-06-27-13-27-02.bpo-37428._wcwUd.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Library/2019-06-27-20-33-50.bpo-37437.du39_A.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Windows/2019-06-18-09-05-08.bpo-35360.tdqSmo.rst
D   Misc/NEWS.d/next/Windows/2019-06-28-08-09-08.bpo-37369.1iVpxq.rst
M   Modules/expat/expat_external.h
M   Python/compile.c
M   Python/peephole.c
M   README.rst
M   configure
M   configure.ac
```

Personally, I prefer using `--stat` to see some statistics about the changes, if it's meant to be consumed by me versus a script:

```
git diff --stat HEAD~10.. --
```

Here's the same example above with `--stat`:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD~10.. --
 Doc/library/http.client.rst                        |  5 ++
 Doc/library/tkinter.rst                            |  4 +-
 Include/patchlevel.h                               |  6 +-
 Lib/http/client.py                                 |  7 ++
 Lib/ssl.py                                         | 29 ++++---
 Lib/test/libregrtest/setup.py                      | 16 ----
 Lib/test/test_httplib.py                           | 18 +++++
 Lib/test/test_ssl.py                               |  9 ++-
 Lib/test/test_syntax.py                            | 14 ----
 Mac/BuildScript/resources/ReadMe.rtf               |  8 +-
 Mac/BuildScript/resources/Welcome.rtf              |  4 +-
 Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4.rst                              | 19 +++++
 Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc1.rst                           |  2 +-
 Misc/NEWS.d/3.7.4rc2.rst                           | 90 ++++++++++++++++++++++
 .../2019-06-22-12-45-20.bpo-24214.hIiHeD.rst       |  2 -
 .../2019-02-03-19-13-08.bpo-32627.b68f64.rst       |  1 -
 .../2019-06-27-13-27-02.bpo-37428._wcwUd.rst       |  4 -
 .../2019-06-27-20-33-50.bpo-37437.du39_A.rst       |  1 -
 .../2019-06-18-09-05-08.bpo-35360.tdqSmo.rst       |  1 -
 .../2019-06-28-08-09-08.bpo-37369.1iVpxq.rst       |  1 -
 Modules/expat/expat_external.h                     |  4 +
 Python/compile.c                                   |  9 ++-
 Python/peephole.c                                  | 15 +---
 README.rst                                         |  4 +-
 configure                                          |  6 ++
 configure.ac                                       |  6 ++
 26 files changed, 209 insertions(+), 76 deletions(-)
```

(note: the output will adjust width based on the terminal in this last version)

Comment: Yes, I guess it depends on the need. To feed it to a script, or constitute a filepack, better have only the list itself, but for human consumption, I'm with you here.

Comment: However.... OP asked : "I only need the filename" so why file statuses? why the diff? why the stats?

Comment: @RomainValeri Because the OP also said he "solved it" by using `git log --name-status --oneline -10`.  So given that answer, it seemed like the OP was actually after something else.  Either way, `git diff` is nice here because you get a list of files touched without having to pipe the result through another command to get a list of unique filenames.  I think `git log` is a less optimal answer, IMHO.

Comment: I don't know why yet, but I compared the outputs of `git log --name-only --pretty=format:"" origin/master..origin/releases` and `git diff --name-only origin/master..origin/releases` and on a work repo I have here, and it yields slightly different results... I have to figure why.

Comment: I wonder if that’s git log’s history simplification at work?  It could be that things like commits being reverted don’t show up using git diff since those changes are no longer present, whereas will show you everything that was touched even if the net result is no change for a particular file.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it... by adding `--oneline`.

```
git log --name-status --oneline -10
```