# How to find out the files I work with changed or not before git rebase?

Tags: git

Working on with big C++ repo, I don't want to waste (a lot of) time recompiling the project after getting fresh changes to master branch.
How can I find out in an elegant way these changes will affect the code I'm working with (in dev. branch) or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list only the names of files that changed between two commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/how-to-list-only-the-names-of-files-that-changed-between-two-commits)

Comment: What are you trying to find out?

Comment: @IMSoP Nope, eg. git diff on master HEAD and dev HEAD will show files changed by me. I want to know if these files have been changed in master by someone else after pull. If yes I will rebase with dev branch, otherwise I will not.

Comment: @amordo The linked question talks about getting the difference between *any two commits*. Perhaps the information you're missing is how to find/reference the current commit of the remote master?

Comment: can you please explain in more details : "fresh changes" do you mean changes that would be brought by a `git pull` on the master branch ? "these changes" the changes between what an what ? (I guess you are interested by the changes *you* wrote on top of `master`, I just don't get the details of what branch/tag/commit is relevant to you)