# List of changed files

Tags: git

How to get list of changed files in a particular changeset? I expected it to be

```
git diff --name-only a329a7b3b85a2f23d2cc2b6c897dc30fb25fa6a5
```

for changes made by me in `a329a7b3b85a2f23d2cc2b6c897dc30fb25fa6a5`, BUT it returns the changes made in the revision that follows right after mine. So I need to find the id of previous changeset :-S

Is it expected behaviour? Why is it?!

Comment: Omg, is it really offtopic? Please look at the `Related` questions list.

Comment: You are getting a diff between the working directory and the given commit.

Comment: @William Pursell: nope, http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html: `This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named <commit>.`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
$ git show --oneline --name-only sha
```

or perhaps

```
$ git show --format=format: --name-only sha
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what I needed. Thanks (will check after 15 minutes cap is reached)