# git: how can I list ALL the files present at a given commit?

Tags: git, list, show

I'd like to get a list of all the files present in git at a given point.

I've tried issuing something like:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only f21b25e76d146
```

This only shows the files that where added though, not ALL the files present
in the working directory at that specific commit. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git ([second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444317/1449460) answers this)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree f21b25e76d146`

Answer (score 0):

gitk can do this easily. Run `gitk f21b25e76d146` and above the lower-right pane, click Tree.