# How to show files added from a commit in git?

Tags: git, version-control

If I have a given commit SHA, what is the best way to show only the files that were added through that commit? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all the files for a commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: That answer didn't specify how to filter the commit for only files added through the commit.

Comment: How about `git show --name-status SHA` or `git show --name-only SHA`?

Comment: That would work but doesn't seem to handle files added through a merge commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research this seems to be a pretty reliable solution.

git show -m --name-status  -1 -U | grep $'A\t'

Comment: Note that this answers the "what does it mean to add a file" question with "if it was not in *any* parent", e.g., if you merge `feature` into `master` and `master` has a file `yoink` that is not in `feature`, you'll see it (even though `master` might be considered the "main line" here).

Answer (score 3):

"Best" is tricky (what's the best flavor of ice cream?) but there are a lot of ways.

Shortest output, but assumes that the commit is not a merge [edit: or, well, see below]:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A <id>^ <id>
```

Easiest way to use this is probably with a git alias:

```
git config alias.files-added '!git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A $1^'
```

(note that running `git files-added` with no arguments will give a weird "bad revision" message, but oh well).

If you need to handle merge commits, you have to decide what it means to "add a file".  Is the file added if it was not in *any* parent?  Is it added if it was not in *all* parents?  For instance, suppose you've merged `subtopic-A`, `subtopic-B`, and `subtopic-C` into `topic`, and file `xyz` was present in both `subtopic-B` and `topic`, but was not present in either `subtopic-A` or `subtopic-C`.  Was `xyz` "added"?

Edit: if the definition of "added" means "was not in what most would call the ‘main line’ before the merge", this same command would work.  That is, if you're on branch `topic` as above, and you merge one or more other branches into `topic` and the final merge commit contains file `galumph` when `topic` did not have a file named `galumph` before, this would be considered "added" (no matter which, if any, of the merged-in branches had it).