# Git checkout all files from exact commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

As I know, to get old version of some file I need input:

```
git checkout COMMIT-HASH -- file-name.ext
```

But if I wont to get all modified files from some commit? Can I input something like:

```
git checkout COMMIT-HASH -- *
```

P.S. I know that I can list files manually, but it's not convenient if there are many files.

Answer (score 22):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, I think one of these two will do the job:

```
git reset --merge <commit>
```

or

```
git checkout <commit> -- .
```

If there are files currently in your working directory that are not in `<commit>`, they will still be there, which might confuse things, depending on exactly why you want to do this. One alternative to get a clean working tree that is only the contents of `<commit>` would be this:

```
rm -r *
git archive --format=tar <commit> | tar xf -
```

For that matter, you could just empty your worktree before the `git reset` or `git checkout` commands above, as well...

None of these will actually move your `HEAD`, which I think is the effect you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I believe that OP's question is resolved with `git checkout <commit> -- .`. He does not seem to intend to move the current branch, so `git reset --merge <commit>` will not help.

Comment: @ShaoWeiTeo OK but that doesn't delete files.

Comment: you can delete files first then checkout. `git reset ` moves the branch head and may cause unexpected things.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but none of the suggestions here helped me. I want to create a new blank branch, and checkout the changes made in a given commit. I have created the blank branch, but I am unable to bring the changed files only, how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this SO question may be of use: [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git)

Basically, to get a listing of the files, you can use `git diff-tree`:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r COMMIT_ID
```

Once you have that, you can feed it to git checkout:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r COMMIT_ID | \
    xargs git checkout COMMIT_ID --
```

So, the `git diff-tree` will help get the list of files, and the `xargs git checkout COMMIT_ID --` will help reset the affected files back to the state they were in at that commit (you're only rolling back those particular files).

You probably need to do this at the top of your working tree.  Also, I didn't try seeing what would happen if there's a rename involved, so there is likely another edge case you might need to consider.  Spaces in path names could be a problem here too, but I didn't see a way to get the paths in a null-terminated format with `git diff-tree`.  Perhaps `git diff` would be better in that case:

```
git diff --name-only -z COMMIT_ID^ COMMIT_ID | \
    xargs -0 git checkout COMMIT_ID --
```

Also, if you really want to go back in that way and there's really only one commit that's the issue, perhaps `git revert` would be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks, your link helps me. Final command that I need is: 
'git show COMMIT_ID | patch -p1'

Comment: Interesting... that's re-applying a commit, which is different that your question. :-)  Glad you found what you needed though.

Comment: I want to do the same, but I am on Windows machine using PowerShell, could you please help me? I am not sure how to use `xargs` nor `patch` commands on Windows.

Comment: I create another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960193/4180447. I hope you can help me with the solution.

Comment: @tarekahf Your link appears to take me to the same question.  You'll need to point me at the new question as I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

How about cherry-pick without commit

```
git cherry-pick COMMIT-HASH --no-commit
```

Comment: This would apply changes from `COMMIT-HASH`, but it would not give you the exact files from that commit. Upstream changes from the target commit would not be included. I believe OP wants to update their workspace with all the files from the target commit.

Answer (score -4):

Just don't pass the filename at all.

```
git checkout COMMIT-HASH
```

Comment: This command moves HEAD to this COMMIT-HASH. I need something like git revert && git reset --mixed HEAD~1 but without resolve any conflicts. 
Just all files from that commit in that state and opportunity watch diff current and those state.

Comment: IIRC, there is a flag to pass to `git reset` that will do that.