# List files changed in Git with change information

Tags: git, git-show

In short I want this:

`git show --name-only <hash>`

([How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git))

But I also want some indication of what kind of change it was, e.g. added, deleted, added/removed n lines, preferably still on a single line per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff-tree <hash> --stat --summary`

`--stat` shows the number of lines added/removed, while `--summary` explicitly shows added and deleted files.