# How to get the list of unstaged files during git-merge?

Tags: git-merge

Is there a way to find the list of unstaged files during merge?
That is, when we merge from branch A to branch B, few files get merged (staged) if there are no conflicts. Suppose if I discard some of them (unstaging/discarding), How will I get the list of those files?

Comment: If you unstaged them, shouldn't you know which files were unstaged?

Comment: Assume I have merged couple of months ago, I wouldn't remember the unstaged files, What if I want to merge those files now again?  That's the reason I want to list the unstaged files during a merge or appropriately listing unstaging files with the merge commit it.

Answer (score 0):

> Assume I have merged couple of months ago, I wouldn't remember the unstaged files.

Agreed: the merge commit would only reflect staged files (automatically merged or resolved after merge conflict)

And don't forget that you could also unstaged part of one file, and merging the trest of that same file.

> What if I want to merge those files now again?

You could, for testing, reset your HEAD to one commit *before* the last merge commit, effectively cancelling that merge.
Then merge again (the same source commit to your moved HEAD) and list the files being merged: `git diff --name-only`

You can compare that list to the one of [the previous merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444317/6309):

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-ish>
```

The difference between the two lists would be the list of files that were unstaged during the initial merge.