# How can I view changed files for each commit in the log?

Tags: git, git-log

I want to view a list of the files that were changed in each commit in `git log`. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit) asked about how to view the changed files for a single commit, and got the [following response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit/424142#424142):

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98
index.html
javascript/application.js
javascript/ie6.js
```

What I want to know is how to apply this to `git log`. That is, what command should I run to get something like the following output?

```
commit 78b3ba12002f9cab5cbb57fac87d8c703702a196
Author: WD40 <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 09:59:57 2017 -0500

    Change more things

    about.html
    javascript/application.js
    javascript/ie6.js

commit 0f98b1f7eda33a4e9cfaab09506aa8094044085f
Author: WD40 <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 09:49:03 2017 -0500

    Change some things

    index.html
    javascript/application.js
    javascript/ie6.js
```

Additionally, if it's possible, I'd like to know how to do the same thing, but also display added and deleted files.

I've looked at the `git log --format` options, but I couldn't find anything resembling what I want. I have a feeling it's not possible with git log, and may require stringing together the output from multiple `git diff-tree`s, but I'm not sure how to go about that either without scripting (which may be the only way to accomplish what I want, but I thought I'd go ahead and ask since that would be my last resort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git-log` has many, many options for displaying the changes. [They're found in the docs as Common Diff Options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_common_diff_options), common because they're shared by many commands which can display commits, like `git-diff-tree`.

`--name-only` is what you want. There's also...

- `-p` to display the complete patch
- `--stat` to display the files changes, and the number of changes
- `--name-status` to show the name and how it changed (modified, deleted, ...)

And much, much more!

So, for example, `git log --name-status` might show something like:

```
commit 78b3ba12002f9cab5cbb57fac87d8c703702a196
Author: WD40 <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 09:59:57 2017 -0500

    Change more things

A      about.html
M      javascript/application.js
D      javascript/ie6.js

commit 0f98b1f7eda33a4e9cfaab09506aa8094044085f
Author: WD40 <example@example.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 09:49:03 2017 -0500

    Change some things

A      index.html
A      javascript/application.js
A      javascript/ie6.js
```

Where `A` is added, `M` is modified, and `D` is deleted.