# How to list all files in a single Git commit with a specific text change in the diff?

Tags: git

I found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/537961) that I can list the files changed in a commit with:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r bd61ad98
```

How can I then to show only the files which include a specific text change in the diff?

Comment: As an aside, you could also use `git diff` (which is probably what I would think to do first, since I try to keep my commonly-used command set minimal).  You then *wouldn't* need the `-r` or `--no-commit-id` flags, but you would have to specify to diff against the parent (`bd61ad98^` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`-G` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#git-diff-tree--Gltregexgt):

> #### `-G<regex>`
>
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match .
>
> To illustrate the difference between `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>`, consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> ```
> +    return !regexec(regexp, two->ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ...
> -    hit = !regexec(regexp, mf2.ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ```
>
> While `git log -G"regexec\(regexp"` will show this commit, `git log -S"regexec\(regexp" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the number of occurrences of that string did not change).
>
> See the pickaxe entry in [gitdiffcore[7]](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore) for more information.

For example:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id -G<regex with what you are looking at> --name-only -r bd61ad98
```