# Git merge not merging all files

Tags: git

I am having a real tough time using git.

I have a branch `A` and a branch `B`. I want to merge branch `A` into branch `B`. I am currently on branch `B` and I used the following command:

`git merge A`.

Now when I run `git status`, I see that I am ahead by two commits and when I look at the files that were altered during the `git merge` I noticed only two files being altered. However, there are at least a dozen files that I know was changed in branch `A` that didn't get picked up during the `git merge`.

Why is `git merge` only merging those two files when there are clearly other files that need to get merged?

Comment: if you committed the changes to branch B, merging will bring the commits over, so the files won't appear on git status, only the commits

Comment: @EvilGeniusJamie Omg, then how can I know which files are being changed ? I care more about the files then the commits.

Comment: I'd say check the docs for `git diff-tree` but... git docs >.< lol. Check out this answer though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit

Comment: @Robin `git diff --name-only branchA branchB`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comparing the two branch tip commits is the wrong thing to do, because that's not what `git merge` does.

To see what files each of you changed, you must first find the commit that branches `A` and `B` most recently *shared:*

```
             o--o   <-- branch-B
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             o--o--o   <-- branch-A
```

(where each round `o` represents a commit, in the chain of commits people have added over time).

The *common commit*, which I marked `*` here, is what Git calls the *merge base* of the two branches.  Git will find this commit automatically, on its own, when you sit at the tip of one of the two branches (such as `B`) and run `git merge A`.

Git will then compare, not `B` vs `A`, nor `A` vs `B`, but rather:

```
git diff hash-of-* hash-of-tip-of-B    # what did *we* change?
```

and:

```
git diff hash-of-* hash-of-tip-of-A    # what did *they* change?
```

The goal of `git merge` is to locate and extract commit `*`, apply *all* the changes from *both* branches, and commit that as a new merge commit on the current branch (`B`), with two parent commits, to make it a *merge commit* so that Git knows what to use as the merge base the *next* time too.

If you want to see the hash ID of commit `*`, you can run `git merge-base`:

```
git merge-base --all A B
```

You can then run `git diff`, giving it that hash ID for the merge base, and the name `A` to select the tip of branch `A` to see what they changed.  You can run a second, separate, `git diff`, giving it that same hash ID for the merge base, and the name `B` to select the tip of branch `B` to see what *you* changed (you might remember what you changed, but it's a good idea to see if Git agrees with your memory, because Git is going to use what *it* finds, not what you remember!).

There is a short-hand that will run `git merge-base` for you, that works only with `git diff`:

```
git diff A...B   # note the three dots
```

will compare the merge base of `A` and `B` against the commit identified by `B`, to find what *you* changed.  A subsequent:

```
git diff B...A   # note the three dots again
```

will compare the merge base of `B` and `A`<sup>1</sup> against the commit identified by `A`, to find what *they* changed.

(You can add options like `--name-status` or `--name-only` to the `git diff` to affect how `git diff` shows the changes it calculates / finds.  Note that whenever there are renames involved, the merge uses the equivalent of `git diff -M50` to find the renames.  Modern Git, since 2.9, enables rename detection in `git diff` as well by default.)

---

<sup>1</sup>"Merge base" is a symmetric graph operation, so "merge base of A and B" is by definition equal to "merge base of B and A".

Comment: This doesn't provide a resolution as to how to make the two branches merge all the files. It just tells me that git is a convoluted unintutitive mess at times.

Comment: @IanSmith: `git merge` *will* merge *from the merge base*, as described. If you want to merge from something other than the merge base, don't use `git merge`. (Consider `git merge-file`, which takes three input *files*, rather than three input *commits*, if you want to specifically take three files and combine them.)

Comment: Say you revert branch A (mainline) to its very first commit and you want to bring everything from branch B (newMainline) to be the next new commit on branch A. Common sense says `git merge` should be the first tool to try but that isn't what should be used? What would be the right tool for this scenario?

Comment: If you mean that you did the equivalent of: `git checkout master; git merge --ff-only $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m urk first-commit-hash^{tree})` so that `master`'s tree now matches the root commit's tree, it's not at all clear what you'd like as the result of "merging" some other commit in the graph. If you have a plan, though, you can make any arbitrary graph you like using `git commit-tree` and then run `git merge` on the resulting commits, knowing how `git merge` works; the resulting *tree* is presumably the set of files you want.

Comment: Note that `git merge` would do nothing in the above case. It's helpful to think of Git as a graph-manipulation tool with a lot of file-updating work attached to the graph operations: see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: @torek Hi, I have a file _foo.py_ that caused a _merge conflict_ at _merge base_. I have a branch _main_ and _other_. I merged _main_ into _other_ by keeping file from _other_.

After some work on _main_, I am merging again _main_ into _other_, the conflict between the _foo.py_ does not triggers anymore (but still the files are branch-wise different, but no respective modification where applied on both versions of _foo.py_).

If I understand correctly, it is due to the fact no resp. modification where applied on both versions of _foo.py_ that the merge does not warn on the _foo.py_ diffs?

Comment: @torek, Note the first merge has a _merge base_ (A) which is different from the later _merge base_ (B), hence it would explain the behaviour.

However, even if technically it makes sense, it is a bit confusing and which _git_ tool does the job of purely merging any modifications ? I mean, I'd like _git merge_ to track the oldest _merge base_ rather than the newest ?

EDIT: Ok, now If I understand correctly the purpose of _git merge_ is to join **development histories**, then everything make sense

I am asking this because the contents of `main...other` and `other...main` differed