# Copy differing files between two commits to a specific folder using Git

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out how to get files from a Git repository that were modified in a given commit. I would like to store the 'delta' in a separate folder. I'm quite new to Git, so this might be relatively basic question, but still..

I thought I should first get the repository at the version:

```
git reset --hard a02ea0d
```

Then list the content of the commit:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only a02ea0d
```

But then what? Can I plumb this together to have some extra folder as a result just with the actual files at the version?

Comment: what do you call "the delta"? Do you mean the diff output? If so that's a single file.

Comment: pretty sure you do not need the reset part to show info about old commits. anyways, do you want the whole new files, the whole old files or just the delta/patch?

Comment: `git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2` this will give you all the files changed from commit `SHA1` to commit `SHA2`.

Comment: I want to get the modified files only (perhaps should not call it the delta?) I dont want the whole repo at given commitid state, i want to extract the fies that were modified in the commit.  I dont want just the names, i want the result to be a folder with the files that were in the commit. Thanks

Comment: Wanna try the command I posted and check out if it gives you the files you actually want?

Comment: @mnagel - i just want the delta/patch which would be the files (and their content) that was  that were modified in the commit. so i want the files in the sate they are in given commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Comment: @DavidMichaelHuber - i am not looking just for file names. I want their content too. So i want to create a new folder that would contain all the files returned  by the command  you suggest.

Comment: Do you want diffs or the whole contents of the modified files?  I can't tell what you are after from your description or your comments. :-(

Comment: @jszakmeister whole files please. Apologies for misuse of some terms. I want content of every file that is in the commit to be copied to a separate folder

Comment: @spiskula I suggested a solution which will copy all the files that differ between two commits into a certain directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

```
git checkout <SHA of old commit>
git diff --name-only <SHA of old commit> <SHA of newer commit> | xargs git checkout-index -f --prefix='C:\changes\'
```

## Explanation

`git checkout <SHA of old commit>` will cause the following `git checkout-index` to copy files out of the old commit.

`git diff --name-only <SHA of old commit> <SHA of newer commit>` will return a list of all files that have been changed between the old and the newer commit.

`xargs git checkout-index -f --prefix='C:\changes\'` will take all the files returned by the first command (by using a pipe) and will use each line as an argument for the following `git checkout-index` command.

## Example

The environment used in this example is a machine running Windows 10 using Git Bash.

- `git init` within a certain folder
- Creat two files

  - file1.txt containing `abc`
  - file2.txt containing `cba`
- `git add` all files afterwards `git commit` them
- Change file1.txt and file2.txt

  - file1.txt containing `abcabc`
  - file2.txt containing `cbacba`
- `git add` all files afterwards `git commit` them
- `git log` and find the SHA1 for the first and the second commit
- Apply the solution I offered above

The folder specified in the command will now contain all the files that changed between the two provided commits looking like this.

- file1.txt contains `abc`
- file2.txt contains `cba`

Comment: The OP seeks all file contents and the names in a certain commit.

Comment: `git checkout-index` will save the files containing differences at the given path.

Comment: I would guess that *most* of the time, you'd want to checkout the new commit instead of the old one, so that you can deploy the newly changed files somewhere. And with the new commit, you probably also want to filter out deleted files.