# How to identify delta changes between two commits in git

Tags: git, delta

I am trying to identify the **delta** changes whenever I commit something to gitlab. The commits can be greater than one.

I am trying to find answer similar to below question
[Copy differing files between two commits to a specific folder using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845109/copy-differing-files-between-two-commits-to-a-specific-folder-using-git)

The solution described in above question says it should give me delta changes only but i am getting the whole files. I require delta changes only.

e.g If i execute below commands

```
git clone <repository location>
git checkout <SHA of old commit>
git diff --name-only <SHA of old commit> <SHA of newer commit> | xargs git checkout-index -f --prefix='C:\changes\'
```

I get the changed file in folder location C:\changes\ . But i need the changed files with delta changes only and not the whole file content.
Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Any suggestions would really help.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

In shell you can do `git diff first-commit-sha1..last-commit-sha2` to get changes between sha1 and sha2.