# GitHub + MEAN: completely resetting remote master

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an Angular app in Visual Studio Code. I also have a remote github repository for this project.

I added Express.js. When I wanted to commit the changes, I got this error when staging the commit:

```
error: open("AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx"): Permission
denied error: unable to index file
AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx fatal: adding files failed
```

My account has permissions for the file, and it's not being used by another application for as far as I can tell.

Long story short: I tried various ways to fix the issue (incl. moving the app folder && creating a clone of the remote repo, replacing the contents and forcing a push) but my remote repository is now a complete disaster. Oh, and all previous commits seem to have been deleted...

Is there any way for me to:

Get around the permission denied error.
Basically overwrite the remote master with the files I currently have, and bring both up to sync?

Answer (score 0):

If is best in that case to:

- close the IDE and other windows in order to minimize the number of processes accessing your local clone
- open an command line in which you can check the state of your repo

A `git log` could show you your past commit, and you could reset your repo to one of those, where you can see your past content in an acceptable state.
List the [files present in a past commit first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/6309).

```
git reset --hard <past-commit>
```

If you don't care about those past commit, and have a working tree currently with the right content, you simply can simply `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.
Make sure first that none of your subfolder has its own .git folder in it: you would be trying to add a nested Git repo, which would not work (ie, you would not add its content, only record its tree SHA1: a gitlink)