# How can I list files changed as part of a particular commit?

Tags: git, git-show

How can I list changes done as part of a particular commit in the format below?

```
repo: agrawalo/interviewing
branch: master 
commit: c917020b 

Batman! This commit has no parent

author: Lokesh Agrawal at 2018-05-16T20:58:17+05:30 

Summary of changes:
pom.xml | 10 +++
+ src/main/java/DBTest.class | 10 +++--
+ src/main/java/DBTest.java  | 8 +++-
src/main/java/com/interviewing/Application.java | 8 ++++
+ src/main/java/com/interviewing/constant/QuestionArea.java | 88 +++-
+ src/main/java/com/interviewing/controller/QuestionController.java | 78 +++--
src/main/java/com/interviewing/entity/Question.java | 17 ++++++
src/main/java/com/interviewing/entity/Skill.java | 23 ++++++++
src/main/java/com/interviewing/repository/QuestionRepository.java | 37 ++++--
+ src/main/java/com/interviewing/repository/SkillRepository.java | 9 ++++++-
+ src/main/java/com/interviewing/service/QuestionService.java | 11 ++++++-
+ src/main/java/com/interviewing/service/QuestionServiceImpl.java | 20 ++++--
src/main/resources/application.properties 13 ++++++
+ src/test/java/com/interviewing/repository/QuestionRepositoryTest.java | 23 +++-----

n files changed, x insertions(+), y deletions(-)
```

I have tried

```
git show --name-only #commithash

commit eaf678f74e35affaeaa21a0df5bf086e804bcad5
Author: Lokesh Agrawal <agrawalo@deshaw.com>
Date:   Fri May 11 12:23:27 2018 +0530

Batman! This commit has no parent

.gitignore
mvnw
mvnw.cmd
pom.xml
src/main/java/com/interviewing/Application.java
src/main/java/com/interviewing/entity/InterviewMatrix.java
src/main/java/com/interviewing/entity/Question.java
src/main/java/com/interviewing/repository/InterviewMatrixRepository.java
src/main/java/com/interviewing/repository/QuestionRepository.java
src/main/resources/application.properties
src/test/java/com/interviewing/StructuredInterviewingApplicationTests.java
```

But it doesn't have an indication on whether files are newly added or something has changed in existing files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Answer (score 0):

`git show --name-only` should do what you want.

**EDIT:**
`git show --name-status` will also show an indication of what changed in the file. E.g. "A" is added and "M" is modified.

Comment: Updated the question with the output of git show --name-only, and reason behind why this doesn't help.

Comment: Is there a way to change A to +. And have a summary at the bottom. 

Something like: "1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)"

Answer (score 0):

Try `git show --name-status`

---

*note :* `--name-only` and `--name-status` are also valid options for `git diff`, `git log`, and a few other git commands

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you can see list of files modified as part of commit using following command:

```
git log --stat
```

This will list down all the commits with list of files modified for each commit.