# git log - find out which commit added a specific file

Tags: git

I know that we can use the command `git show --pretty="" --name-only 90e34953` to [list all files from a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/4684797).

Is it possible to execute git log and include all files from the commits to the output?

Maybe there is a script which runs through each commit and inserts it into the command above?

e.g. (pseudocode)

```
$out = "";
foreach($commit in $commits) {
    $out .= $commit
    $out .= "----------------------------------------"
    $out .= (git show --pretty="" --name-only $commit)
}
$out > logfile.txt
```

We try to find out which commit added a specific file.

Comment: `git log`, like `git show`, takes a `--name-only` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --diff-filter=A -- file
```

[--diff-filter=A](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) filters those commit(s) that add the file.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to find out which commit added the file is:

```
git log --reverse -- <file>
```

The top most commit is the one that has added the file.