# How to get diff between two git push?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am working on git repo which has no `git flow` setup means it does not have master, develop, feature branch. I cloned this repo and I have created a branch `test_branch` and I made changes on my local branch and did multiple commits then pushed them. Now, I would like to find out list of files I have pushed.

All the `git diff` commands I found are comparing with `origin/master`, HEAD and so but in my case this will not be available . I will push my changes by setting up an upstream like `git push -u origin test_branch`. In such scenario how can I find list of files which I have pushed?

I have tried following commands but not matching with my requirement

- `git log --name-only pattern=""`
- `git diff origin/master...`

`git log` shows complete information on local branch but I need only files which I have pushed. After one `git push` I might do one more set of commits and doing `git push` I need only files which I pushed recently.

I am getting this error when I try with `origin/master`.

**`fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`**

I am looking for a command which is purely depend on local branch to find out the pushed files.

**EDIT:**  [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)  will not solve my problem becuase,

1. I do not have commit ids
2. I need list of files from multiple commits not from last or recent commit.

Comment: I'm not a git expert, but what if you do not use origin/master but actually your branch name. like for example `git diff --name-only test_branch` ?

Comment: @ the hand of NOD  You are comparing with same branch , how it will find the diff, gives no output.