# List all files in a directory not changed by a specific git commit

Tags: git

I know that a git commit changed multiple files in the directory
`src/java/task`

It want to list all files in that directory that were **not** changed as part of that commit.

Real world context: I'm reviewing changes by someone and believe they should have made a similar change to every file in that directory. I want to know any files they didn't change in their commit (that may have been missed, or actually didn't need changing but I want to examine why).

Comment: Sounds like you want a command which lists all files in a repo then filters out changed files in the commit?

Comment: I found something like `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | xargs -n1 -I % sh -c 'tree -fia . | grep -v %', but I don't see how useful this is.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes although actually I only care about a specific sub-directory of the repo in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use bash:

```
comm -23 <(find src/java/task | sort) <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $COMMIT_HASH | sort)
```

`comm` takes two files and generate an output with three columns, first column are lines unique to file1, second column are lines unique to file2 and third column are lines that appear in both files.

We take as the first file a list of all files in directory src/java/task:

```
find src/java/task | sort
```

As a second file, the files that were changed since last commit

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $COMMIT_HASH | sort
```

We need the files unique in the first file (files not changed) so we only need the first column. Using -23 as a parameter of comm will supress column 2 and 3, so we only get the first column.

Notice that you need need to sort the results of every file.

You may need to tweak this a bit but more or less that's a way to do it.

Comment: `find .src/java/task` didn't work as all lines then started with `.src` whereas the lines from git started `src` (no .) so all lines were show as different. Instead I used `find src/java/task`

Comment: Also for the second file I used this to get the list of files changed in the commit: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r` _`commit-hash`_ as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/184325

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

commit=$1

# all files under src/java/task/, excluding subfolders
all=$(git ls-tree ${commit}:src/java/task | awk '/ blob /{print "src/java/task/"$4}')

# files changed by the commit
changed=$(git show ${commit} --pretty= --name-only)

# files not changed by the commit
for f in ${all} ${changed} ${changed};do
    echo ${f}
done | sort | uniq -u
```

Suppose the script is `foo.sh`, the repository is at `/path/to/foo/`, and the commit is `HEAD`. To run the script,

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/foo/.git bash foo.sh HEAD
```

There may be a git command with some magic options to do the job, but I can't find any yet.

Comment: I haven't tried this to know if it would have worked how I wanted since I was already testing the other answer before this was posted.