# Can we perform a Jenkins job only on the files within a pull request instead of the whole repository?

Tags: jenkins, ant, pull-request, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

I want to design a Jenkins job that will trigger when a pull request is created and perform a static code analysis only on the java files that have been modified.

I've already created a Jenkins job that is triggered on pushes and scans a repository for 1 error by following this video and cloning his repository to my bitbucket: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRgYd-SLyrs. So far the job only works on the App.java file but I want it to work on only the files being pull requested. Has anyone done anything like this? I'm in the beginning stages so any kind of guidance will help.

Comment: Have you tried just get the list of changed files (addressed here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit) and remove the rest ? Not sure if the code analysis will work reliably on an incomplete project.

Answer (score 0):

This basically depends on the tool you are using for the static analysis of the code. I can propose a plan which you have to implement in Jenkins.

1. Identify the files changed in the most recent commit. Use `git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1`
2. Invoke your static analysis tool in such a way it scans only the files identified in the 1st step. There should be a way to pass this information to your tool via command line.

Comment: Im trying to edit the job to implement your idea which I think will work. I'm confused about how a Jenkins job knows what files to act on. Is there a file or something I can edit that will tell the job where to get those files?