# Github Action on pull_request - process files changed in the current commit

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I have a github action workflow that gets triggered

```
on: pull_request 
uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35.
uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

It also gets triggered on every commit pushed to the PR requesting branch which is desirable but it picks up **ALL the changed files** in that branch from the beginning of the PR and not just the **files changed in the latest commit**. This is causing issues with my action logic. How can I procure only the latest commit changes in my action?

Has anybody used another action for changed-files that can provide this functionality?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit

Comment: If you can modify the action then you can query the Push Event payload for `github.sha` which should be the current commit sha - [see here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) for everything the incoming Github context provides Action creators.

After you have the `github.sha` you can use the REST API or GraphQL to query what files were changed there.

Comment: You can simply use the since_last_remote_commit input. See: https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files?tab=readme-ov-file#input_since_last_remote_commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any special GitHub action step to get the changes made in the current commit. You can simply use [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to list files changed in the commit. See the link (mentioned in the comment) on [How do I list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-do-i-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit).

Keep in mind that, by default, when the workflow run is triggered by the [`pull_request` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) webhook the `checkout` action does not use the PR branch HEAD to clone the repo:

> Note that [`GITHUB_SHA`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) for this event is the last merge commit of the pull request merge branch. If you want to get the commit ID for the last commit to the head branch of the pull request, use [`github.event.pull_request.head.sha`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) instead.

The `github.event.pull_request.head.sha` property of the [`pull_request` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) webhook can be used as `ref` parameter to the [`checkout` action](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v3) step to obtain the latest commit hash of the pull request branch to clone. Then use the `git diff --name-only HEAD^` command to list the changed files between the latest commit and its parent (previous) commit. The command uses the `^` symbol to refer to the previous commit. In other words, it will show you only the changes made in the latest commit.

By default, GitHub Actions [`checkout` action step](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v3) fetches only the last commit without the history of other commits (to speed up the operation and save disk space required for executing the workflow run).

> Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. Set `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all history for all branches and tags.

This is not enough to successfully execute `git diff` command. The operation requires at least two commits to be available in the git working tree to perform the comparison between each other. So, to be able to do the `git diff` comparison you will need not only the latest commit but the previous one has to be also included in the `checkout` step to successfully execute the command. In your case, setting the `fetch-depth: 2` will be enough because only `2` commits (the latest one and the previous one) are required to make a `git diff`.

Putting all the above together you get the solution:

```
on: pull_request
jobs:
  process-last-commit-changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout (fetch last two commits) of the PR
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: Process files changed in the current commit
        run: |
          changedFiles=$(git diff --name-only HEAD^)
          for file in $changedFiles; do
            echo "Processing file: $file"
          done
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but this can be achieved by setting the `since_last_remote_commit` input to `true`

```yaml
      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v42
        # To compare changes between the current commit and the last pushed remote commit set `since_last_remote_commit: true`. e.g
        with:
          since_last_remote_commit: true
```