# How to list all files in a folder of a commit?

Tags: git

To [list all the files in a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424071/3416774), I can use:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98
```

However if I want to further narrow down the list to only files in a folder, what should I do? How about files not just in one folder but:

- in several folder?
- not in a folder?
- not in several folders?

Comment: You can't do this with `git show`.

Either check out the commit and use `git ls-files`, or use `grep` to filter the output of `git show`.

Comment: Files are not "stored" in commits. If you want to see changes between commits, you can always use `git diff`.

Comment: `git show --name-only` doesn't list **all** files in the commit, it only list files changed from the previous commit. Do you want to list **all** files or modified files?

Comment: @phd I see. I want to list all files

Comment: `git ls-tree --name-only -r bd61ad98 subdir1 subdi2`

Answer (score 2):

`git ls-tree $commit:$path` answers your question as asked, but I think you're after all the files that *changed* in that folder.

`git diff-tree -m $commit{~,}:$path`, with `--name-status` or `--name-only` if you want, or if you want the full path listed and not the that-path-relative names, `git diff-tree -m -r $commit{~,} -- $path`.

For multiple paths, either run multiple commands or use the separated form, `$commit{~,} -- $path` and give multiple paths; to take all paths except some see [the pathspec docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec), you can use `":!$path"`

```
$ git diff-tree -m -r --name-status @~20{~,} -- ':!t' ':!Documentation' 
M       contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh
M       contrib/subtree/t/t7900-subtree.sh
M       parse-options.c
$ git diff-tree -m -r --name-status @~20{~,} -- # ':!t' ':!Documentation' 
M       Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt
M       contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh
M       contrib/subtree/t/t7900-subtree.sh
M       parse-options.c
M       t/t0040-parse-options.sh
M       t/t1502-rev-parse-parseopt.sh
A       t/t1502/.gitattributes
A       t/t1502/optionspec-neg
A       t/t1502/optionspec-neg.help
A       t/t1502/optionspec.help
$
```

Comment: How can this be used to exclude multiple folders at the same time?

Comment: Multiple folders, just list them all. Exclusion, see the pathspec docs in `git help glossary`, `':!path'`

Comment: So something like `git diff-tree -m -r bd61ad98{~,} ':!foo' ':!bar'` ? that seems to throw ugly errors if any of the folders do not exist

Comment: I added a `--` separator to disambiguate the args, that made that little wart go away. It was (wrongly imo) trying to interpret them as revisions first and getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `awk`.

---

In folder `foo`:

```bash
$ folder="foo"
$ git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98 | awk -F'/' -v folder="$folder" '$1 ~ folder'
```

Not in folder `foo`:

```bash
$ folder="foo"
$ git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98 | awk -F'/' -v folder="$folder" '$1 !~ folder'
```

Not in folder `foo` nor `bar`:

```bash
$ first_folder="foo"
$ second_folder="bar"
$ git show --pretty="" --name-only bd61ad98 | awk -F'/' -v first_folder="$first_folder" -v second_folder="$second_folder" '$1 !~ first_folder && $1 !~ second_folder'
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but this will not work for interior folders like `foo/bar`, and the extension to nested folders is not going to be easy to find for anyone who'd need to ask this question.

Comment: @jthill it can easily be adapted for internal folders, but OP didn't specify that requirement